# EventListenerList firing order

Tags: java, swing, event-listener

In a Swing application, I have a number of sub-panels, each listening to a single [`JSlider`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JSlider.html). The surrounding parent panel also listens to all the sub-panels. To get consistent results in the example below, I had to add the parent first and *then* the local listener. This makes sense, given the order prescribed in [`EventListenerList`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/event/EventListenerList.html) and explained in this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559488/why-is-eventlistenerlist-traversed-backwards-in-firefooxxx). Can I rely on that order or should I arrange to send a different event?

```
class SubPanel extends JPanel implements ChangeListener {

    private final JSlider slider = new JSlider();
    private final JLabel label = new JLabel();
    private final String name;
    private float value;

    public SubPanel(String name, float value, ChangeListener parent) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
        ...
        slider.addChangeListener(parent);
        slider.addChangeListener(this);
    }
    ...
}
```

Addendum: the discussion in [`EventListenerList`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/event/EventListenerList.html) appears to be implementation advice rather than a guarantee. The chaining approach suggested by [pstanton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/145574/pstanton) enforces the correct order more reliably. For example, the `SubPanel`'s `ChangeListener` can simply forward the event to the parent.

```
    @Override
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        ...
        parent.stateChanged(e);
    }
```

Comment: Interesting question and discussion! 1+

Comment: The [`Converter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html) application includes an example in `ConverterRangeModel`.

Comment: I just got your post while `googling`, wanted to explain in details. please make the post count, and point me out if anything i have described can be wrong!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the documentation for JSlider and JComponent etc don't mention the order of listener notification, I would hesitate to rely on it, at least without thorough testing on each subsequent version of the JRE.

If you really need to rely on the order, consider setting up a chain of listeners, ie Listener one will notify listener two etc.

Comment: Generally on state change (as opposed to input) events it is more robust to completely ignore the event object. (Don't be confused about performance - think about how many cycles you are using compared to *millions* an average CPU can do in a millisecond).

Comment: @Tom: is that a comment on my answer, or his question?

Answer (score 2):

A bit old and very late to answer. But My unstable mind is really forcing me to snick into.

> Can I rely on that order or should I arrange to send a different
>   event?

I do believe that they maintain the order, the Component's documentation doesn't tell us much, but ***source code*** is always our friend. Let us start from `addChangeListener(listener)` function of `JSlider`:

**STEP 1:** calling `jSlider.addChangeListener(listener)` adds the `listener` to a `listener list`.

```
public void addChangeListener(ChangeListener l) {
        listenerList.add(ChangeListener.class, l);
    }
```

**STEP 2:** source code of `EvenListenerList`: `synchronized add(Class<T> t, T l)`: adds the listeners and corresponding type such that new listener is added at the end of the `Object[]` and for an index `i`,`Object[i]` is type of the listener and `Object[i+1]` is the listener instance.

```
public synchronized <T extends EventListener> void add(Class<T> t, T l) {
    // There were other checking here
    // omitted as irrelevant to the discussion
    } else {
        // Otherwise copy the array and add the new listener
        int i = listenerList.length;
        Object[] tmp = new Object[i+2];
        System.arraycopy(listenerList, 0, tmp, 0, i);

        tmp[i] = t;  // add the class type
        tmp[i+1] = l;  // add the listener instance 

        listenerList = tmp;
    }
    }
```

**STEP 3:** The `fireStateChanged()` function of `JSlider` is responsible for sending event to every listener of the list. The source code tells us that it call each listener's `stateChanged()` function by visiting them from the end of the listener list.

```
protected void fireStateChanged() {
        Object[] listeners = listenerList.getListenerList();
        for (int i = listeners.length - 2; i >= 0; i -= 2) {
            if (listeners[i]==ChangeListener.class) {
                if (changeEvent == null) {
                    changeEvent = new ChangeEvent(this);
                }
                ((ChangeListener)listeners[i+1]).stateChanged(changeEvent);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Summery:** The mechanism of (synchronized)adding and visiting of listeners in listeners list tells us that: it maintain the LAST ADD FIRST VISIT order. That is, the later(child) added listener is going to be called first, then the previous(parent) added listener and so on. Swing event handling code runs on EDT. And as `EventQueue` dispatches the event In the same order as they are `enqueued`, the child event will be dispatched prior to parent event.

So I do believe the **order** is being maintained.

Comment: While an interesting design pattern, it's an implementation detail on which I'm reluctant to rely.

Comment: probably, but to me, calling the `EventListListener` mechanism *unreliable* seems we are scolding it :) ;)

Comment: just for emphasizing @trashgod's comment: the order of notification is explicitly unspecified (see f.i. the beans spec). Also, the order can change during the lifetime of an observable, f.i. by removing/adding listeners on LAF change. So, as a general rule **don't** rely on any concrete implementation, it might change without notice!

Comment: Ok, i will look into the specification. I need to be convinced