# What is a class literal in Java?

Tags: java, literals

From the [Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html):

> Finally, there's also a special kind of literal called a *class literal*, formed by taking a type name and appending "`.class`"; for example, `String.class`. This refers to the object (of type `Class`) that represents the type itself.

To what type of variable can this literal be assigned to?

Please give a small example if possible.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

```
Class<String> c = String.class;
```

Check out the [Javadoc for `java.lang.Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) to see what you can do with one of these little guys - mostly related to reflection

Answer (score 43):

To understand that, you have to understand that **String** is an instance (object) of the class **Class**.  A string literal (e.g. "I am a string.") is a notation which represents an instance (object) of the class **String**, whereas a class literal (e.g. Hashtable.class) is a notation which represents an instance of the class **Class**.

Comment: @shinkou String is an instance (object) of the class Class. How come? It should be "String.class is an instance (object) of the class Class" right?

Comment: @Ani String itself is also an instance of the class Class which is assigned the class literal String.class.  Think of `String str = "I am a string";`, where `str` is assigned a String literal "I am a string".

Comment: `String` itself is NOT an instance of class `Class`. It has a literal, `String.class`, that is an instance of `Class<String>`. If it was an instance of type `Class`, then `String.class` would be an instance of `Class<Class>`. `String` is not an instance of anything.

Comment: @LewBloch I omitted the `.class` to try to make things easier to understand.  A class literal can't do anything without its type afterall.

Comment: @shinkou, whatever the motivation, incorrect statements do not "make things easier to understand". _Au contraire_, they engender misunderstanding and confusion. Don't spread untruth.

Comment: @shinkou, it made things clear for me, thanks :)

Answer (score 27):

Thanks to the other good answers here, you know what it is, but here's a typical usage example that may clarify also:

```
    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(YourClassHere.class);
```

As the code suggests, this is a line where we're initialising a logging framework (in this example, I'm using the `org.apache.log4j` package, but the principle extends to other frameworks). The `getLogger()` method requires a class literal so it knows what it's logging (i.e. the current object's class).

Comment: This is, to be, about a 1000 times more helpful than quoting JavaDocs or some other definition; Thank you!

Answer (score 18):

According to the [*Java Language Specification (JLS)*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.2):

> 15.8.2 Class Literals
>
> A class literal is an expression consisting of the name of a class, interface, array, or primitive type followed by a `.` and the token `class`. The type of a class literal is `Class`. It evaluates to the Class object for the named type (or for `void`) as defined by the defining class loader of the class of the current instance.

Answer (score 6):

Some common uses may be found in [*Class Literals as Runtime-Type Tokens*](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/extra/generics/literals.html). The approach is widely used to implement the [*observer pattern*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern), as seen in the [`EventListenerList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/event/EventListenerList.html), discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2159803/230513). The [`Converter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html) application includes an example in `ConverterRangeModel`.

Answer (score 5):

The literal itself is `MyClass`. If you write `MyClass.class` you get a Reference to the class object. If you write `new MyClass()`, it uses the literal to get you an instance of the class object you get by `MyClass.class`. From the instance you get the same class object by calling `myClassInstance.getClass()`.

I am not 100% sure, but the literal itself cannot be assigned to any variable. What you can do is getting the name of the class as string and use the reflection framework to create an instance.

Comment: Sure you can. If not, you would not be able to pass it as a parameter to a function. The type of the literal is Class<E> which can be assigned to references of that type.

Comment: The literal itself is not the class name. Per https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.2 the class literal is the token `class`. From the JLS: "A class literal is an expression consisting of the name of a class, interface, array, or primitive type, or the pseudo-type void, followed by a '.' and the token class." Note that it is not the name of the class, but the name followed by `.class`.

Answer (score 3):

In examples it is someting like that:

```
Class myClass = MyClass.class
```

or

```
MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("config.properties");
```

Answer (score 1):

To understand that, you have to understand that `String` is an `instance (object)` of its `superclass (parent class)` `Object`.

`class String`'s `instance (object)`'s value is a `String literal` (e.g. `"I am a string."`) :

```
class   |  instance (object) |  literal
------------------------------------------------
String  |  instance_name  =  |  "I am a string."
```

whereas `class Object`'s `instance (object)`'s value is a `Class literal` — (e.g. `Hashtable.class`) which refers to `class Hashtable`'s `instance (object)`

```
class      |  instance (object) |  literal
------------------------------------------------
Hashtable  |  instance_name     |  Hashtable.
```

Comment: `String` is not an instance of anything, and certainly not of any superclass.

Answer (score 1):

When the JVM loads your application classes, it stores them as `java.class.Class` objects.

So, there are usually several instances of type `Class` in memory that represents your classes. So you can do something like this:

```
Class<Bicycle> bicycleClass = Bicycle.class; // returns the object storing your Bicycle class
bicycleClass.getName();  // returns your class name
bicycleClass.getDeclaredMethods();  // returns your (declared) class methods
```

Answer (score -1):

```
package training;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class Training {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Class<Training> myclass = Training.class;
        Method[] myclassarr = myclass.getDeclaredMethods();
        System.out.println(myclass);
        System.out.println(myclass.getName());
        for (int i = 0; i < myclassarr.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(myclassarr[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();
        Class<String> strobj = String.class;
        System.out.println(strobj);
        System.out.println(strobj.getName());
        Method[] strobjarr = strobj.getDeclaredMethods();
        for (int j = 0; j < strobjarr.length; j++) {
            System.out.println(strobjarr[j]);
        }
    }

    public void MethodA() {

    }

    public static void MethodB() {

    }
}
```

> Output:

```
class training.Training
training.Training
public static void training.Training.main(java.lang.String[])
public void training.Training.MethodA()
public static void training.Training.MethodB()

class java.lang.String
java.lang.String
public boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)
public java.lang.String java.lang.String.toString()
public int java.lang.String.hashCode()
public int java.lang.String.compareTo(java.lang.String)
public int java.lang.String.compareTo(java.lang.Object)
public int java.lang.String.indexOf(java.lang.String,int)
public int java.lang.String.indexOf(java.lang.String)
public int java.lang.String.indexOf(int,int)
public int java.lang.String.indexOf(int)
static int java.lang.String.indexOf(char[],int,int,char[],int,int,int)
static int java.lang.String.indexOf(char[],int,int,java.lang.String,int)
public static java.lang.String java.lang.String.valueOf(int)
public static java.lang.String java.lang.String.valueOf(long)
public static java.lang.String java.lang.String.valueOf(float)
public static java.lang.String java.lang.String.valueOf(boolean)
public static java.lang.String java.lang.String.valueOf(char[])
public static java.lang.String java.lang.String.valueOf(char[],int,int)
public static java.lang.String java.lang.String.valueOf(java.lang.Object)
public static java.lang.String java.lang.String.valueOf(char)
public static java.lang.String java.lang.String.valueOf(double)
public char java.lang.String.charAt(int)
private static void java.lang.String.checkBounds(byte[],int,int)
public int java.lang.String.codePointAt(int)
public int java.lang.String.codePointBefore(int)
public int java.lang.String.codePointCount(int,int)
public int java.lang.String.compareToIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)
public java.lang.String java.lang.String.concat(java.lang.String)
public boolean java.lang.String.contains(java.lang.CharSequence)
public boolean java.lang.String.contentEquals(java.lang.CharSequence)
public boolean java.lang.String.contentEquals(java.lang.StringBuffer)
public static java.lang.String java.lang.String.copyValueOf(char[])
public static java.lang.String java.lang.String.copyValueOf(char[],int,int)
public boolean java.lang.String.endsWith(java.lang.String)
public boolean java.lang.String.equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)
public static java.lang.String java.lang.String.format(java.util.Locale,java.lang.String,java.lang.Object[])
public static java.lang.String java.lang.String.format(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object[])
public void java.lang.String.getBytes(int,int,byte[],int)
public byte[] java.lang.String.getBytes(java.nio.charset.Charset)
public byte[] java.lang.String.getBytes(java.lang.String) throws java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException
public byte[] java.lang.String.getBytes()
public void java.lang.String.getChars(int,int,char[],int)
void java.lang.String.getChars(char[],int)
private int java.lang.String.indexOfSupplementary(int,int)
public native java.lang.String java.lang.String.intern()
public boolean java.lang.String.isEmpty()
public static java.lang.String java.lang.String.join(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence[])
public static java.lang.String java.lang.String.join(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.Iterable)
public int java.lang.String.lastIndexOf(int)
public int java.lang.String.lastIndexOf(java.lang.String)
static int java.lang.String.lastIndexOf(char[],int,int,java.lang.String,int)
public int java.lang.String.lastIndexOf(java.lang.String,int)
public int java.lang.String.lastIndexOf(int,int)
static int java.lang.String.lastIndexOf(char[],int,int,char[],int,int,int)
private int java.lang.String.lastIndexOfSupplementary(int,int)
public int java.lang.String.length()
public boolean java.lang.String.matches(java.lang.String)
private boolean java.lang.String.nonSyncContentEquals(java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder)
public int java.lang.String.offsetByCodePoints(int,int)
public boolean java.lang.String.regionMatches(int,java.lang.String,int,int)
public boolean java.lang.String.regionMatches(boolean,int,java.lang.String,int,int)
public java.lang.String java.lang.String.replace(char,char)
public java.lang.String java.lang.String.replace(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence)
public java.lang.String java.lang.String.replaceAll(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
public java.lang.String java.lang.String.replaceFirst(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
public java.lang.String[] java.lang.String.split(java.lang.String)
public java.lang.String[] java.lang.String.split(java.lang.String,int)
public boolean java.lang.String.startsWith(java.lang.String,int)
public boolean java.lang.String.startsWith(java.lang.String)
public java.lang.CharSequence java.lang.String.subSequence(int,int)
public java.lang.String java.lang.String.substring(int)
public java.lang.String java.lang.String.substring(int,int)
public char[] java.lang.String.toCharArray()
public java.lang.String java.lang.String.toLowerCase(java.util.Locale)
public java.lang.String java.lang.String.toLowerCase()
public java.lang.String java.lang.String.toUpperCase()
public java.lang.String java.lang.String.toUpperCase(java.util.Locale)
public java.lang.String java.lang.String.trim()
```

Comment: I have just answered what the person has asked in the question. "To what type of variable can this literal be assigned to?

Please give a small example if possible."

Comment: My mistake for just posting the code. Please find below the link to get more details about - class literal in Java.                               
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/details-class-literal-java-nisrin-dhoondia