# which toString() method can be used performance wise?

Tags: java, performance

I am working on one project for performance enhancement. I had one doubt, while we are during a process,  we tend to trace the current state of the DTO and entity used. So, for this we have included toString() method in all POJOs for the same. I have now implemented toString() in three different ways which are following :-

```
public String toString() {
    return "POJO :" + this.class.getName() + " RollNo :" + this.rollNo + " Name :" + this.name;
}

public String toString() {
    StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer("POJO :").append(this.class.getName()).append(" RollNo :").append(this.rollNo).append(" Name :").append(this.name);
    return buff.toString();
}

public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("POJO :").append(this.class.getName()).append(" RollNo :").append(this.rollNo).append(" Name :").append(this.name);
        return builder .toString();
    }
```

can anyone please help me to find out which one is best and should be used for enhancing performance.

Comment: I'm sure you can write a benchmark in 2minutes.  Why guess when you can measure?

Comment: the benchmark would show results, yes, but it's good to know these things theoretically.

Comment: possible duplicate of [StringBuilder vs String concatenation in toString() in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532461/stringbuilder-vs-string-concatenation-in-tostring-in-java)

Comment: "I am working on one project for performance enhancement" - use a profiler, and identify which section of the code is actually worth looking at and optimizing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The one with the `+` is fine in this case. It's more readable, and it's just as performant compared to the `StringBuilder/StringBuffer` version, since it' doesn't happen inside a loop.

If you are building a `String` inside a loop, then more often than not you should use `StringBuilder`. Only use `StringBuffer` if you need its `synchronized` feature, which doesn't happen very often.

Simplistically speaking (not true always, but is a good rule of thumb), unless you're doing a `+=` with a `String`, you don't really need a `StringBuilder/StringBuffer`.

#### Related questions

- [StringBuilder vs String concatenation in toString() in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532461/stringbuilder-vs-string-concatenation-in-tostring-in-java)
- [String, StringBuffer, and StringBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2971315/string-stringbuffer-and-stringbuilder)
- [StringBuilder and StringBuffer in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355089/stringbuilder-and-stringbuffer-in-java)

---

#### A `String.format` option

One option often not considered is to use [`String.format`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29). It'll look something like this:

```
return String.format("POJO : %s RollNo %s : Name : %s",
   this.getClass().getName(),
   this.rollNo,
   this.name
);
```

I find that this is the most readable and maintainable version.

Is this faster? Maybe yes, maybe not. It usually doesn't matter for common use case scenarios for something like `toString()`. Strive for readability, only optimize if profiling says it's necessary.

#### API links

- [`java.util.Formatter` syntax](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)

---

#### On Class Literals

I've corrected a syntax error in the original code from `this.class` (which doesn't compile) to `this.getClass()`.

#### See also

- [JLS 15.8.2 Class Literals](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.8.2)

#### Related questions

- [What is a class literal in Java ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160788/what-is-a-class-literal-in-java)

Comment: *"Is this faster?"* - almost certainly not because `format` has to parse the format string, and the caller has to allocate and fill a varargs array. But as you say, it probably doesn't matter.

Comment: @Stephen: yep, I'd be very surprised if `format` is faster, but I try not to develop even a basic instinct for these kinds of things, and to just trust a profiler instead.

Comment: Also, I think you can cache the class name in a `static final String`, but I doubt that it'd make too much of a difference. OP should use a profiler and find an actually worthy piece of code to optimize.

Answer (score 9):

*Use the 1st one, because it's more readable.*

But otherwise, it doesn't matter.

- Using `StringBuilder` and `+` in this case is equivalent, because the compiler translates the overloaded `+` operator to a `StringBuilder`.
- the `StringBuffer` will be slower, due to its methods being `synchronized`, but since [escape analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_analysis) (more specifically - synchronization elision) might used by the compiler (in newer versions), it will automatically remove the `synchronized` keyword. (See [JDK 6u14 release notes](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/webnotes/6u14.html) to learn about escape analysis)

Comment: Whoa! Which JVM runtime does synch elision? This is the first time I heard of such a (cool!) feature!

Comment: @polygenelubricants since JDK 6u14 it is available, but not on by default I think. See http://java.sun.com/javase/6/webnotes/6u14.html for how to turn it on.

Comment: not so fast.  *"Unfortunately escape analysis-based optimisation, which was enabled in update 14, has been disabled again in update 18 to be re-instated at some future date."*

Comment: Escapse analysis is there in 6u20, but I don't know what it does with this analysis because it doesn't appear to make it faster. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Use the first one. I'll explain why.

The naive view is to use the last one. There's no reason to use the second one. A `StringBuffer` is the same as a `StringBuilder` except it has a performance hit from `synchronized` locks. But don't put it on one line. This is much more readable:

```
public String toString() {
  StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder(("POJO :");
  out.append(this.getClass().getName());
  out.append(" RollNo :");
  out.append(this.rollNo);
  out.append(" Name :");
  out.append(this.name);
  return out.toString();
}
```

That being said, you have to be careful about this kind of micro-optimization. Why? Because the compiler will often do this for you. So write whatever is most readable and let the compiler optimize it.

So the major lesson here is: **don't micro-optimize**.

Ultimately though, it probably doesn't matter which one of 1 or 3 you use. `toString()` methods don't *tend* to be used a huge amount in an application. More commonly they're used in error messages, which are hopefully infrequent.

Comment: Why bother using a StringBuilder explicitly? The first form will use one implicitly anyway, and without the extra cruft.

Comment: I know the compiler will turn the first version into the third, but it's hell to debug this generated version because what happens is not what you see in your source code, so I tend to use the third version.

Comment: @Seanizer Do you often need to debug your toString() methods? Usually I place a breakpoint on the one line in my toString and look at the variable values in my debugger and it tells me what is likely to cause an Exception.

Comment: @seanizer: you can take that logic further and argue that the only correct way to write code is in assembly, because that's what "actually happens", right? No, I disagree. Abstraction is good. _Ignorance_ of abstraction is bad, but abstraction itself is good. The more the better.

Comment: @Peter, @Poly no I don't often debug toString methods, but I often debug methods of third party libraries where string concatenation happens inside a method call and I have to do a lot of f5 / f7 in eclipse in order not to miss the actual statement I am interested in. Yes, abstraction is good, but in this case abstraction has a price that often bugs me. and the assembler point is irrelevant, because my debugger fortunately does not step through assembler calls. but "what happens" was a bad choice of wording, I agree

Answer (score 2):

This is more readable IMO

```
public String toString() { 
    return String.Format("POJO : {0} RollNo : {1} Name : {2}",
                          this.getClass().getName(),
                          this.rollNo,
                          this.name);
}
```

Comment: Maybe in C# it's like that, but not in Java. Also, `this.class` doesn't compile.

Comment: in java it's MessageFormat.format(...) with identical parameter syntax (actually I'd use this.getClass(), not getClass().getName(), no need to evaluate the toString before it's needed). btw, this.class doesn't compile as many have already mentioned