# what does .class mean in log4j context

Tags: java, log4j

In log4j, I need to use

```
Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class);
```

I want to know what is the meaning of MyClass.class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a "class literal" - a way of getting the instance of [`Class<T>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) representing `MyClass`. It will give you the same result as calling `this.getClass()` from within an instance method of an object of type `MyClass`.

The Java Language Specification, [section 15.8.2](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.8.2) has more details:

> A class literal is an expression consisting of the name of a class, interface, array, or primitive type, or the pseudo-type void, followed by a `.` and the token class. The type of a class literal, C.Class, where C is the name of a class, interface or array type, is `Class<C>`. If p is the name of a primitive type, let B be the type of an expression of type p after boxing conversion (§5.1.7). Then the type of p.class is `Class<B>`. The type of void.class is Class.
>
> A class literal evaluates to the Class object for the named type (or for void) as defined by the defining class loader of the class of the current instance.

Comment: Is this similar to typeof? In C# version log4n, we use GetLogger(typeof(MyClass))

Comment: @user496949: Yes, it's the Java version of `typeof` basically.

Answer (score 1):

`.class` is a property that returns the runtime instance of the class itself.  You can find more information in [What is a class literal in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160788/what-is-a-class-literal-in-java).

In log4j, different loggers can be configured for different classes, so when you instantiate the logger with that class, the log level, appenders, and other configuration can be controlled for each class.

Answer (score 0):

`Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class)` is used to get the full name of your class (say "com.you.package.MyClass"), and that string is used to configure this Logger object.

Log4j uses a hierarchy to determine what to do for a given logger, and the more specific instructions (say for "com.you.package") override the instructions from higher up (say for "com.you").  See the configuration file for details.

Comment: The log4j manual is a book you may want to buy.   There is a short version available at http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html

Comment: I do think it is really a java language question.

Comment: @user496949, your language could be interpreted as what the .class construct means in log4j context.  If that is not what you mean, I suggest you edit your question for clarity.

Comment: Myclass.class is a class literal, it is NOT "is used to get the full name of your class, that string is used to configure this Logger object". I do not think .class returns a string.

Comment: @user496949, I skipped the toString() call as I believed you were interested in log4j configuration details.

Comment: Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen, it makes sense to me now.