# Was the class literal syntax necessary?

Tags: java, syntax, keyword

I know well, [what is a class literal in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160788/what-is-a-class-literal-in-java), I just wonder, what is the reason for the `.class` in the syntax. Is there any ambiguity removed by this? I mean, wouldn't an alternative Java syntax using

```
Class<String> c = String;
```

instead of

```
Class<String> c = String.class;
```

work? To me the `class` keyword looks like a boilerplate.

Comment: the real question is why can't you do `Method m = String.toString` or so

Comment: @Kitsune: uh, because Java doesn't support first-class functions. Incidentally, you _can_ do that like this: `Method m = String.class.getMethod("toString");` but it's slow, throws exceptions, and is ugly as sin (esp. when invoking it).

Comment: @Kitsune you can - look into the reflection library.

Comment: @Matt - actually, it has nothing to do with the lack of first-class functions.  it's just a lack of the relevant syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you *could* make that the syntax. But using the `.class` suffix makes the compiler's job easier; it has to do less work to know that the code is syntactically correct.

Without the suffix, the compiler would have to work harder to understand the difference between this:

```
String.getName() // a method inherited from java.lang.Class<T>
```

and this:

```
String.valueOf(...) // a static method from java.lang.String
```

---

If you don't think that the `.class` suffix is needed, do you also think that the `f` and `L` suffices are useless (for `float` and `long` literals, respectively)?

Comment: `L` is extraneous on large values but definitely needed if you do `50L * 1000000 * 1000000`; you will get overflow otherwise. `f` is necessary to disambiguate from doubles.

Comment: Strange that I didn't see this ambiguity myself. @ide - agreed, that's a different thing.

Comment: @ide: of course you're right. Much of Java syntax is about giving the compiler "hints" — that is, being as explicit as is reasonably possible, and minimizing the guesswork.

Answer (score 1):

It's just not the same thing. `String` is a class of type string, and `String.member` is one of its member variables, `String.method()` would be one of its methods.

`String.class` is an object of type `Class` that defines `String`. It seems a lot more intuitive that you need to specify `.class` to indicate that you're trying to refer to an object of type `Class`.

Not to mention that it's easier to parse this kind of construct, and potentially prevents bugs where you're accidentally returning a `Class` object when you didn't mean to.

This is even more relevant when you're looking at inner classes, like `OuterClass.InnerClass.class`.

To work with Matt's example: How would you work on the class object without having to create a temporary variable first? Assuming your class `Foo` has a static method called `getClasses`, how would you differentiate between `Foo.getClasses` and `Foo.class.getClasses`?

Comment: I think your first paragraph's argument doesn't hold any water. The OP asks _why_ this is the case. I agree with the rest, though, since it's similar to what I said in my answer.

Comment: Yeah, but that's somewhat of an implicit conversion - one thing Java is very eager to avoid. String by itself is "a class of type String", not "a Class object defining String". I understand that it may sound appealing to just make it one and the same, but it isn't.

Comment: @EboMike @Matt Ball I agree that there are cases when the disambiguation is needed. However, the most common use of `X.class` is for passing it as argument (and is getting more and more common, when using reflection, annotations, etc). So I'd prefer to have the possibility to omit it normally, and use something like `String.class.getName()` and `String.static.valueOf(....)` when necessary.

Answer (score 1):

`String` is the String class pseudo-object which provides access to the classes static fields and methods, including `class`, which refers to the `Class` instance which describes the String class. So they are distinct, but because Java doesn't have the metaclass arrangement of (say) Smalltalk-80 this isn't very clear.

You could certainly make `String` and `String.class` synonymous if you wanted to, but I think there is a valid basis for the distinction.

Answer (score 0):

Let's use integer as an example:

```
Class<Integer> c = Integer; // your proposal
int i = Integer.MAX_VALUE; // compare with below
int j = c.MAX_VALUE; // hmm, not a big fan, personally
```

It just doesn't seem to flow, in my opinion. But that's just my opinion :)

Comment: For that matter you can do `Integer i; i.MAX_VALUE;`. I don't find this convincing.

Comment: You 'can', but it also produces a warning (for good reason - it just doesn't flow...)

Comment: @ide: that's only because of a (dubious) language decision which allows static methods to be called non-statically.