# Java T initialize

Tags: java, wcf, generics, collections

How to create class of T?

I need to bind from some Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) XML of the object T.

**I can do this without errors:**

```
ArrayList<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
```

**This is my function:**

```
public static <T> ArrayList<T> GetListFromXml(String url,String element)
```

How to get: T obj = ?

Comment: Did you work through the [Java Generics tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not possible due to the [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) of the compiler. If you have a concrete type with a default constructor on caller side, the following may work:

```
public static <T> ArrayList<T> GetListFromXml(String url,String element, Class<? extends T> type) {
  T obj = type.newInstance();
  ...
}
```

If you need to pass parameters to the constructor, you have to get it from the class by `getConstructor(parameter type 1, ...)` (you need to handle the Exceptions not shown here):

```
MyParamType1 param1 = ...;
MyParamType2 param2 = ...;
Constructor<T> cons = type.getConstructor(MyParamType1.class, MyParamType2.class);
T obj = const.newInstance(param1, param2);
```

Comment: `ArrayList<YourClass> ycList = GetListFromXml(url, element, YourClass.class);`. [Class literals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160788/what-is-a-class-literal-in-java).

Comment: can i send prameters to the constractor?

Comment: @user1194088 You can send the type as a parameter to a class which takes a parameter e.g. if you write one.  ArrayList doesn't take a type.

Comment: i meant sent prameters to the T constractor,