# How does a class literal work?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a class literal in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160788/what-is-a-class-literal-in-java)

I was going through literals in [the Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) where I came across this sentence:

> Finally, there's also a special kind of literal called a class literal, formed by taking a type name and appending ".class"; for example, `String.class`. This refers to the object (of type Class) that represents the type itself.

Which doesn't make any sense to me, even though I paid attention to all the other topics prior to this. Can anyone explain in simple language with examples or references?

Comment: Which part don't you understand?

Comment: It's a reference to the Class object which represents the `Xxxx` before the .class.  Perhaps you imagine it to be more complicated than it is. ;)

Answer (score 4):

Instances of the class [`java.lang.Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) represent classes and interfaces in a running Java application. For each class in the application, there is an instance of `Class`. The `SomeClass.class` syntax is a way to get from `SomeClass` to the corresponding instance of `Class`.

Comment: Would it be worth adding "without instantiating a new `SomeClass`" or is that obvious?  I know that `.class` is really usful with things like dependency injection and ORMs where the characteristics of a class are not known at compile time

Answer (score 2):

A class literal is just a special type to use when you want to do something involving the class itself, rather than an instance.

Here's a short list of a few things I commonly use this for (not at all comprehensive, but you can get a good idea)

1.) Reflection, you want to instantiate something in run-time that you may not know (perhaps it was stored in a variable of type Class)

2.) You want to check if 2 objects are of the same related type, you can write something along the lines of: `B.class.isAssignableFrom(a.getClass());`

3.) You want to list all the methods, or public variables within a class, perhaps for documentation.

There are many other uses, but these are the main ones I find myself using in common practice.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking simple language: that thing, which you call `class literal` is an object which fully describes some `class`: all its methods, all its fields, all its annotations, class's modifiers and so on. It is needed for creating new instances of that class in runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Short example:

```
    Class x = String.class;
    System.out.println(x);
```

you can use `x` to create runtime instances of the class it points to or to test the class of an object against it.

Answer (score 0):

It evaluates to be the class identifier of the reference or primitive type's wrapper class. The expression void.class evaluates to the class identifier of the Void class. Same thing with 'String.class'