# What exactly is ".class" in Java Source Code

Tags: java, reflection

I was surfing in SO & I found syntax in Java as below:

```
String.class.getDeclaredField("value");
```

I could not understand how it works

**Example:**

In `System.out.println();`  `out` is static variable in System class of PrintWriter

Can any one explain what `String.class.getDeclaredField("value");` and it's returning object of `Field` class means?

I just looked & I couldn't find class property(field) in String class.

What is it actually doing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read about java reflection api.

Comment: Please learn what is Class class and Reflection in Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String.class` is a literal that represents the  `String` class which is of type `Class<String>`. [`getDeclaredField()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredField%28java.lang.String%29) is a method defined on the class `Class`.

see also: [What is a class literal in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160788/what-is-a-class-literal-in-java)

The literals are defined in the [Java Language Specification 15.8.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.2)

Comment: but i didnt found in String class where should i look for it?

Comment: It's not a method or field it is part of the class literal syntax

Comment: where this all literal defined? where can i found it? in oracle's site 
sorry because i am asking out of topic(just near to it?)

Comment: @PulahNandha I added a link to the answer

Answer (score 0):

Look up `Java Reflection` API and `Class.getDeclaredField()`.

Comment: Thanks for the cosmetic cleanup, Octopus. I've been up all night, so was a bit more terse than optimal.