# Java EnumMap Parameter confusion

Tags: java, enum-map

I'm working with an EnumMap for the first time, and don't understand what the parameter pass is actually doing.  As far as I can tell it's just "K.class" where K is the map key.  This works just fine, but I haven't seen this anywhere else in Java and I'm not clear on what role it's actually playing in the construction.

I guess this is a theoretical question because the code runs: what does the "K.class" parameter mean, and what does the EnumMap need it for?

Comment: [What is a class literal in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160788/what-is-a-class-literal-in-java)

Comment: What part don't you understand exactly?

Comment: `<K, V>` would be gone from `Map<K, V>` after the type-erasure is applied by the compiler. But, at runtime the `Map` implementation needs to know exactly what enum class you are talking about. So you have to specify the class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See the linked question for [class literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160788/what-is-a-class-literal-in-java).

`EnumMap` specifically needs it, because it needs to know how many different values the enum has. This is because EnumMap is a highly optimized map implementation for enums that uses only one array with one slot for every possible value (instead of a much larger array like a HashMap). When you call `get()`, it retrieves the index of the given key (i.e., the first enum value, the second etc.) and looks in the appropriate position of its internal array. For this the constructor needs to know the number of possible values to allocate an array of the correct size.
Given the class object, it can call [`getEnumConstants()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getEnumConstants%28%29) to find out the number of existing values for this enum.

Furthermore, imagine the following code:

```
enum Enum1 { V1, V2; }
enum Enum2 { W1, W2; }
EnumMap<Enum1, Object> map = new EnumMap<Enum1, Object>(Enum1.class);
map.put(Enum1.V1, new Object());
map.get(Enum2.W1);
```

Now the `get` method should obviously return `null`. However, as I said, the map internally has only one array, in this case of size 2, with the new object in the first slot and null in the second. It did not store a reference to Enum1.V1 when you passed it to `put()`. However, the method `get` now needs to know that the passed value does not belong to the correct enum, and thus there is no value for this key in the map. Here too it needs the type of the correct enum, and for this you need to pass the type to the constructor.

Without you giving some information about the enum to the constructor, it would not know which enum you intent to use with this map instance. Even if you write new `EnumMap<MyEnum, SomeValue>()`, the constructor cannot know about the value `MyEnum` of the generic type parameter due to type erasure. Thus there needs to be another way to pass the information to the constructor.

Comment: Thanks for this, I follow now.  I'm familiar with generics, which meant that a lot of the other comments and discussion elsewhere didn't help.  I was only casually acquainted with class literals, and so I didn't understand the need for one because I hadn't considered that type erasure prevented just checking the key type.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the source of `EnumMap`: It appears that when you construct an `EnumMap`, one of the first things it does is to allocate an array that has one element for each enumeration constant in the `enum` class.  `EnumMap` is supposed to be efficient, so it makes sense that it would be allocating a fixed array.  To do this, it needs to know the class.  If it weren't for type erasure, this could be done by looking at `K.class` where `K` is the first type parameter in `EnumMap<K,V>`.  Unfortunately, the design of Java generics prevents this.

Comment: Before looking at an implementation, one should first check the specification. It says "Enum maps are represented internally as arrays."