# Finding T.class in the documentation

Tags: java

Cay Horstmann in his book Core Java describes this method for obtaining an object of type Class

> If T is any Java type, then T.class is the matching class object. For
>   example:

```
Class cl1 = Date.class; // if you import java.util.*; 
Class cl2 = int.class; 
Class cl3 = Double[].class;
```

> Note that a Class object
>   really describes a type, which may or may not be a class. For example,
>   int is not a class, but int.class is nevertheless an object of type
>   Class.

I've scanned through java.util and can't explain what is written here. That "class" seems to be a field. A field of an Object class. Though it contradicts to what is written by Mr. Horstmann who references to java.util. Could you point at where can I read about it in javadoc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not in javadoc because it's not a method you call - it's part of the syntax of the language. It's a *class literal*, which is described in the [Java Language Specification section 15.8.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.2):

> A class literal is an expression consisting of the name of a class, interface, array, or primitive type, or the pseudo-type void, followed by a '.' and the token class.
>
> The type of `C.class`, where `C` is the name of a class, interface, or array type (§4.3), is `Class<C>`.
>
> The type of `p.class`, where `p` is the name of a primitive type (§4.2), is `Class<B>`, where B is the type of an expression of type `p` after boxing conversion (§5.1.7).
>
> The type of `void.class` (§8.4.5) is `Class<Void>`.

Answer (score 2):

```
// if you import java.util.*;
```

The `Date` class is in `java.util`, so you need to `import` it. That statement has nothing to do with class literals, which is what the syntax of `TypeName.class` is called.

[What is a class literal in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160788/what-is-a-class-literal-in-java)

[Class literals in the Java Language Specification.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.2)

> A class literal is an expression consisting of the name of a class,
>   interface, array, or primitive type, or the pseudo-type `void`, followed
>   by a `'.'` and the token `class`.
>
> A class literal evaluates to the `Class` object for the named type (or
>   for `void`) as defined by the defining class loader (§12.2) of the class
>   of the current instance.