# Java Class Generic Expression Syntax

Tags: java, generics, syntax, expression

```
Test test1 = new Test();
```

> here, **new Test()** means create new instance of class Test and assign it
>   to reference test1.

```
Class<Test> test2 = Test.class;
Test test2Instance = test2.newInstance();
```

I am not able to define (in words) 1st statement. On the other hand 2nd statement it pretty clear to me.

**EDIT**

> String is an instance of the class **Class**.
>
> A string literal (e.g. "I am a string.") is an instance of the class
>   **String**.
>
> class literal (e.g. **Hashtable.class**) is an instance of the class
>   **Class**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Class<Test> test2 = Test.class;
```

This statement declares a variable named `test2`, of type `Class<Test>`. It initializes this variable with the unique instance of this type, using the class literal expression `Test.class` which refers to the class `Test`.

Comment: .@JB Nizet you included "class literal expression" in your answer give me clue and i googled it and come to a link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160788/what-is-a-class-literal-in-java and I got it what i am looking for.

Comment: `Test.class` is indeed a class literal. Just like `1` is an integer literal and `"hello"` is a String literal.

Answer (score 1):

```
Class<Test> test2 = Test.class;
```

means "give me the `Class` object representing the `Test` class and store it in the variable `test2`.

Aside from `Class` being generic, this has little to do with generics. It's about class objects.

Answer (score 0):

`Class<Test>` is a specific type of a generic type. Literally you are defining a variable `test2` which is of type `Class<T>` with `T == Test`.

`Class<T>` is a parametric type, it depends on T, if you add the constraint `T == Test` then you are talking about a variable of `Class<Test>` (which is a specific different type).

It's orthogonal compared to polymorphism by subtype. If you have

```
class Base { .. }
class Derived extends Base { .. }
```

and you write

```
Derived derived = ...
```

You have no problems in stating that you are declaring a variable named `derived` of type `Derived`. This is the same thing, but `Class<Test>` is not a subtype of `Class<T>` but a specialization of it.