# Obtaining .class from a class with type arguments

Tags: java, generics

Why is this not possible?

`List<Foo>.class`

Or more specifically let `A` be a class with a type parameter (i.e. `class A<T> { // code }` why is `new A<T>().getClass()` possible while `A<Foo>.class` a compiler error?

Comment: see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2160974/180100)

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390662/java-how-do-i-get-a-class-literal-from-a-generic-type (cletus answer)

Answer (score 2):

In generics, the part within < and > is just an option for the Generic class.

In your example, the class is List, so you would type List.class (or list.getClass() if it's instantiated)

List<T> is just a List, with exactly the same class. T is only used by the compiler to check for consistency.

Answer (score 0):

`new A<T>().getClass()` returns the exact same object as `A.class`.  `Class` objects represent raw types without generic information.  `A<T>.class` would just be lying as to what it actually represents, so it is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a fair question.

This works fine:

```
    Class c = new ArrayList().getClass();
    c= ArrayList.class;
```

This does not:

```
    c = new ArrayList<String>().getClass(); // still ok
    c = ArrayList<String>.class;  // compilation fails
```

The result would always be the same with or without the generic type.

This `new ArrayList<String>().getClass()` does not bring anything more compared to `new ArrayList().getClass()` and it is accepted.

This `ArrayList<String>.class` does not bring anything more compared to `ArrayList.class` and it is not.

So, why?

Probably it is the compiler doing its best to prevent us from writing useless code.