# Why do we give class literals of annotation to the getAnnotation method?

Tags: java, annotations

Why we give class literals of annotation to the getAnnotation method?
For example I want to get the class annotation and put Annotation preceding the Class.

```
@interface MyAnno {
 String str();
 int val();
}
class JavaApplication22 {
```

Why I can't get the annotation of the Class with second method?How class literals work in this situation?

```
MyAnno anno = m.getAnnotation(MyAnno.class); //First Method
MyAnno anno = m.getAnnotation(MyAnno);       //Second Method
```

Comment: `m.getAnnotation(MyAnno)` (where `MyAnno` is a type) is not valid Java code. What do you think it should do?

Comment: I don't except m.getAnnotation(MyAnno) works.But I don't understand how MyAnno.class expression works.What it gives us?I print MyAnno.class and gives output like this "interface javaapplication22.MyAnno".

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/2160788/2891664 and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/literals.html

Comment: Thank you.Is Class<> ancestor of other all class? In this example MyAnno.class returns Class<MyAnno>.But print says that it is an interface.