# .class after an Interface with Custom Events in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, events, interface, listener

I'm learning about Java Swing and I have found an advanced code (in my opinion) about Swing using MVC and Observer patterns. It is very difficult for me and I try to understand it. And I have 2 questions:

1. What exactly does DetailListener.class? It is the first time when I use .class after an interface. I have tried to search on stackoverflow about ".class syntax" and I see it can be used after a class, but I still don't understand what it does in this situation.
2. What exactly does the method fireDetailEvent()?

Thanks in advance!

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class App {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                JFrame frame = new MainFrame("Hello world Swing");
                frame.setSize(500, 400);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

MainFrame

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

    private JTextArea textArea;

    public MainFrame(String title) {

        super(title);

        Container c = getContentPane();

        c.setLayout(new BorderLayout()); 

        textArea = new JTextArea();

        DetailsPanel detailsPanel = new DetailsPanel();

        detailsPanel.addDetailListener(new DetailListener() {

            public void detailEventOccurred(DetailEvent event) {

                String text = event.getText();
                textArea.append(text); 
            }
        });

        c.add(textArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        c.add(detailsPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
    }
}
```

DetailsPanel

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.event.EventListenerList;

public class DetailsPanel extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5115286206114930420L;

    private EventListenerList listenerList = new EventListenerList();

    public DetailsPanel() {

        Dimension size = getPreferredSize();
        size.width = 250;
        setPreferredSize(size); 

        setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Personal details"));

        JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel("Name:");
        JLabel occupationLabel = new JLabel("Occupation:");

        JTextField nameField = new JTextField(10);
        JTextField occupationField = new JTextField(10);

        JButton addBtn = new JButton("Add");

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();

        ////// First column /////
        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;


        gc.weightx = 0.5;
        gc.weighty = 0.5;

        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 0;
        add(nameLabel, gc);

        gc.gridy = 1;
        add(occupationLabel, gc);

        ////// Second column /////

        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;

        gc.gridx = 1;
        gc.gridy = 0;
        add(nameField, gc);

        gc.gridy = 1;
        add(occupationField, gc);

        //////  Final row /////

        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
        gc.weightx = 10;
        gc.weighty = 10;
        gc.gridy = 2;
        add(addBtn, gc); 

        addBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                String name = nameField.getText();
                String occupation = occupationField.getText();

                String text = name + ": " + occupation + "\n";
                System.out.println(text); 

                fireDetailEvent(new DetailEvent(this, text));

            }
        });
    }

    public void fireDetailEvent(DetailEvent event) {

        Object[] listeners = listenerList.getListenerList();

        for (int i = 0; i < listeners.length; i += 2) {

            if (listeners[i] == DetailListener.class) {

                ((DetailListener)listeners[i+1]).detailEventOccurred(event);
            }
        }
    }

    public void addDetailListener(DetailListener listener) {

        listenerList.add(DetailListener.class, listener);
    }

    public void removeDetailListener(DetailListener listener) {

        listenerList.remove(DetailListener.class, listener); 
    }
}
```

DetailListener

```
import java.util.EventListener;

public interface DetailListener extends EventListener {

    public void detailEventOccurred(DetailEvent event);
}
```

DetailEvent

```
import java.util.EventObject;

public class DetailEvent extends EventObject {

    private String text;

    public DetailEvent(Object source, String text) { 

        super(source);
        this.text = text;
    } 

    public String getText() {

        return text;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*1) What exactly does DetailListener.class?*

From the [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html):

> Instances of the class Class represent classes and interfaces in a running Java application.

This is somewhat confusing so let's look at a an example.  Calling DetailListener.class provides its Class representation.  In this specific case `DetailListener.class` provides a `Class<DetailListener>` so it's possible to do this:

```
Class<DetailListener> cdl = DetailListener.class;
```

`cdl` is just another variable similar to how `frame` is just another variable. 
 `frame` happens to be a `JFrame` which provides some methods, while `cdl` is a `Class<DetailListener>` which provides a different set of methods.

`cdl`'s type is a `Class<DetailListener>` which represents the `DetailListener` class.

*but I still don't understand what it does in this situation*

Consider this code:

```
listenerList.add(DetailListener.class, listener);
```

`listenerList` is of type `EventListenerList`.  According to its [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/event/EventListenerList.html#add(java.lang.Class,T)), the `add(...)` method parameters require a Class and a T instance.  In this case, the generic T is DetailListener.  So far the listener has been registered but it leads into your next question.

*#2 What exactly does the method fireDetailEvent()?*

When the listener was registered the `listenerList` keeps an internal array which can be referenced later.  The array holds both the Class and the actual listener instance.  So invoking

```
Object[] listeners = listenerList.getListenerList();
```

provides access to the array.  In this case:

```
listeners[0] = DetailListener.class
listeners[1] = reference to the anonymous inner class instance created from detailsPanel.addDetailListener(...)
```

So the loop in `fireDetailEvent(...)` is guaranteed to be a multiple of 2 (0 also works if there are no registered listeners).  But `listenerList` could hold **any** type of listener, so

```
if (listeners[i] == DetailListener.class) {
```

uses the Class to check for equality to make sure it's safe to caste to be able to pass the `DetailEvent` to the listener (which is the next element in the array).   Using `==` (instead of `.equals()`) is okay in this context since DetailListener.class always provides the same Class.

Answer (score 0):

1. > What exactly does `DetailListener.class`?

   `DetailListener.class` is a so-called class literal.
   Basically, it is a constant of type `Class` referring to the
   `DetailListener` type.

   You can find more and better explanations about this at
   [What is a class literal in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160788/what-is-a-class-literal-in-java)
   and its answers.
2. > What exactly does the method `fireDetailEvent()`?

   Your `DetailsPanel` class uses an `EventListenerList` for handling event
   listeners and sending events to them.

   The comment given in class [EventListenerList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/event/EventListenerList.html)
   gives a detailed description how to use it.
   Read this description and you will recognize, that the methods
   `addDetailListener`, `removeDetailListener` and `fireDetailEvent`
   of your class `DetailsPanel` are written exactly following this description.

   The method `fireDetailEvent` fires a `DetailEvent` to all those listeners
   which have registered themselves earlier by `addDetailListener`.