# Parameters, return value of static ServiceLoader.load() method?

Tags: java, service, serviceloader

Actually this a three part question.

When I looked at the documentation of `static ServiceLoader.load()` method of `ServiceLoader` class it contained

`public static <S> ServiceLoader<S> load(Class<S> service)`

***1*** I need to know how to call this method, what is this parameter `Class<S> service`?

Assumed `SomeClass` is an interface or abstract class,

I saw in examples it used `ServiceLoader.load(SomeClass.class)`

***2*** What is `class` keyword doing in here can't we simply support `SomeClass` as the parameter?

like this,

`ServiceLoader.load(SomeClass)`

In the documentation it contained this method returns a new service loader, I'm confused with this.

***3*** Does this method returns an array of all the implementations of the interface?

Comment: 1. Did you read [the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ServiceLoader.html#load(java.lang.Class))? 2. `SomeClass.class` is a [class literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160788/what-is-a-class-literal-in-java). 3. No. It returns a `ServiceLoader<S>`.

Comment: @AndyTurner yes yet I'm confused with the use of `class` keyword in ServiceLoader.load(SomeClass.class)

Comment: Maybe this can help understand => `Class` is also a `class`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `Class<S> service` is the class of the service type; e.g. Interface or Abstract class that should be implemented by service providers. `load` method is a static method, so to call it just use `ServiceLoader.load(SomeService.class)` syntax.
2. In `load(Class<S> service)` parameter is the the class of the service type; So `.class` should be indicated when calling this method.
3. The `load(Class<S> service)` returns a new instance of `ServiceLoader` class. This class implements `Iterable` interface. When you invoke `iterator()` for this instance, an iterator will be returned that lazily loads providers for this loader's service.

Here a sample code is provided that meybe helps. The `Adapter` interface is the service that should be implemented by service providers:

```
import java.util.Map;

public interface Adapter {
  String getName();

  String getApiVersion();

  void initialize();

  int calculateScore(Map<String, String> data);
}
```

And `AdapterManager` class is used to load service providers:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ServiceLoader;

public final class AdapterManager {
  private final static ArrayList<Adapter> adapters = new ArrayList<>();
  private final static AdapterManager INSTANCE = new AdapterManager();

  private AdapterManager() {
    load();
  }

  private static void load() {
    updateAdapters(findServiceProviders());
  }

  private static List<Adapter> findServiceProviders() {
    ServiceLoader<Adapter> serviceLoader = ServiceLoader.load(Adapter.class);
    List<Adapter> providerList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Adapter provider : serviceLoader) {
      providerList.add(provider);
    }
    return providerList;
  }

  private static synchronized void updateAdapters(List<Adapter> adapterProviders) {
    adapters.clear();
    adapters.addAll(adapterProviders);
  }

  public static AdapterManager getInstance() {
    return INSTANCE;
  }

  public void reload() {
    load();
  }

  public Adapter getAdapter(String name) {
    if (name == null) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Adapter name must not be null");
    }

    for (Adapter adapter : adapters) {
      if (name.equals(adapter.getName())) {
        return adapter;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```