# the relationship between evet listener and event source in Java

Tags: java, swing

what is the relationship between evet listener and event source in Java ?
and i have another question 
what is the difference between java application and java applet ?

any help

thanks in advance

Comment: By custom, please ask just one question per question.

Comment: Read the [Swing tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html). The section on "How to Write Event Listener" would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

1) A good starting point is [`EventListenerList`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/event/EventListenerList.html), discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159803/eventlistenerlist-firing-order).

2) An `Applet` runs in a browser and an application runs on the desktop.

Comment: Also in reference to Application vs. Applet, Applets run in a security sandbox where they typically have less permissions than an application, such as accessing the local file system.