# JPanel does not generate MouseEvents when cursor is on child components

Tags: java, swing, events, jpanel, listener

It is a bit strange for me but JPanel does not generate MouseEvents when cursor is on child components: JTextField and JToolBar but it generates MouseEvents when cursor is on JLabel. Could someone explaind me why? Is there any way to force JPanel to generate events even if mouse is on child components?

Comment: Could you post a snipit or two of relevant code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The event dispatcher will forward mouse events to the listeners registered to the component that is returned by the package-level `getMouseEventTarget` method in `Container`.  This will be called on your `JFrame`, and, as the JavaDoc indicates, it:

> Fetchs the top-most (deepest) lightweight component that is interested in receiving mouse events.

The event dispatcher then takes this top-most component (your `JTextField`, for example) and sends events to all of its listeners only.  They do this in order to avoid having to broadcast these events to all of the components that may be layered within a Swing container.  MouseEvents, as you can imagine, are very chatty, what with all of the `mouseEntered`, `mouseDragged`, and `mouseMoved` events that are dispatched for all of the `MouseListener` and `MouseMotionListener` implementations potentially out there.  The processing to find all listeners and then fire events to all of them in the hierarchy would be time consuming.

The assumption is also that for classes like `JTextField` and `JButton`, etc., the default mouse handling is all that one would need.  If you want to handle mouse actions differently (ie, changing color on a `mouseEntered`/`mouseExited`), you can add a `MouseListener` to these widgets as you need to.

For your processing, I would suggest simply adding your `JPanel` as a `MouseListener` to your top level components if you need to handled these events.

Comment: +1 Interesting; `getMouseEventTarget()` has _package-private_ (no explicit modifier) access in `java.awt`, but most IDEs allow browsing the source.

Answer (score 2):

you may want to have the child components (JTextField, JToolBar, etc) listen for the mouse events from the jpanel and/or forward the mouse events to the child components.

Comment: +1 I think forwarding is the right idea, but @guest may want to forward events from the child component to the parent `JPanel`, as suggested in this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159803

Answer (score 1):

> Could someone explain why?

`Component` mouse events are handled by [`processMouseEvent()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#processMouseEvent%28java.awt.event.MouseEvent%29), which says

> Mouse events are enabled when one of the following occurs:
>
> - A MouseListener object is registered via addMouseListener.
> - Mouse events are enabled via enableEvents.

You can use [`getMouseListeners()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getMouseListeners%28%29) to see the difference.

Comment: +1, Cool, I didn't know a getMouseListeners() method existed. I've always used the generic getListeners(...) method. This will make life a little easier in the future.

Comment: @camickr: Interesting; I didn't know `getListeners()` supported a class literal type-token, _à la_ `EventListenerList`. Sadly, the +1 seems to have gone missing. :-)

Comment: Oops... the +1 has been found.