# Detecting mouse click on JPanel even when the click is on the panel's child

Tags: java, swing

My code has a JPanel that contains a JTextPane that covers most of the JPanel. I would like to detect a mouse click if the event occurs anywhere in the panel, but the JTextPane blocks the event, unless I register a listener to it. Is there some easy way to observe the event without adding in listeners for every child?

Comment: This might help you: [jpanel-does-not-generate-mouseevents-when-cursor-is-on-child-components](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087521/jpanel-does-not-generate-mouseevents-when-cursor-is-on-child-components)

Comment: @Hovercraft, Pete, I followed your link. I understand why the default behaviour is different. I'm wondering if there is any way to get the text field to behave the same as the label. It just happens that I asked this question (http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=9771505&#9771505) earlier tonight. If you or anybody else can shed some more light it would be appreciated.

Comment: Edit to my above comment. I found the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a [Global Event Listener](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/08/30/global-event-listeners/) to listen for the mouse events.

You can use:

```
SwingUtilities.isDescendingFrom(...);
```

to help determine if the component that generated the event is a child of the panel.

Comment: Answering questions is a great way to learn. You pick up tips and learn about classes from others in the forum. Whenever I hear about a new class I check out the API for other methods in the that might be useful. Of course the problem is remembering them all when you don't use them all the time :)