# Java event propagation stopped

Tags: java, events, swing

I have a main window:

```
public class MainPanel extends JFrame implements MouseListener {

   public MainPanel() {
      setLayout(new FlowLayout());
      setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      addMouseListener(this);

      ChildPanel child = new ChildPanel();
      add(child);

      JPanel spacer = new JPanel();
      spacer.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
      add(spacer);

      pack();
      setLocationRelativeTo(null);
   }

   @Override
   public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
      System.out.println("Mouse click event on MainPanel");
   }
}
```

And a child JPanel:

```
public class ChildPanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener {

   public ChildPanel() {
      setBackground(Color.RED);
      setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
      //addMouseListener(this);
   }

   @Override
   public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
      System.out.println("Mouse click event on ChildPanel");
   }
}
```

With the call to `addMouseListener` commented out in the child panel, the parent receives click events when I click anywhere in the window, including on the child. If I uncomment that call and click on the child panel, *only* the child receives the click event and it doesn't propagate to the parent.

How do I stop the event from being consumed by the child?

Comment: Thats weird... I remember having the OPPOSITE problem where the parent was consuming the child bound mouse events

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can.  I believe it's a Swing design principle that only one component receives an event.

You can get the behavior you want, however, but pass the `JFrame` to the `ChildPanel` and calling its `mouseClicked(MouseEvent)` or whatever method you want.  Or just get the parent component.

```
   @Override
   public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
      System.out.println("Mouse click event on ChildPanel");
      this.frame.mouseClicked(e);
      getParent().mouseClicked(e);
   }
```

Comment: I'm wary of the tight coupling implied by this approach.

Comment: Looks like I'm going to go with getParent() unless I can think of a way to change my project so both the parent and child don't need to handle the event. Restricting event handling to one component seems like a ridiculous design decision to me...

Answer (score 5):

In Swing, you generally want the clicked component to respond; but you can *forward* the mouse event to the parent, as shown below. Here's a related [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159803).

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/** @see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605086 */
public class ParentPanel extends JPanel {

    public ParentPanel() {
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640, 480));
        this.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Mouse clicked in parent panel.");
            }
        });
        JPanel child = new JPanel();
        child.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(320, 240));
        child.setBackground(Color.blue);
        child.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Mouse clicked in child panel.");
                ParentPanel.this.processMouseEvent(e);
            }
        });
        this.add(child);
    }

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("MouseEventTest");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(this);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new ParentPanel().display();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: See also [*`EventListenerList` firing order*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2159803/230513).

Comment: How can you propagate the event if you can't access the parent?

Comment: I'd loo at `SwingUtilities` and the extensions mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17631267/230513).