# Wrong Mouselistener fires

Tags: java, swing, components, jpanel, mouselistener

I made a program in Java in which you can draw Ellipses and Rectangles, then later group them to do Resizes and Move actions on them.

I add `MouseListener`s to both the `DrawPanel(JPanel)` as all the created Shapes(Components on that drawPanel). But after I group several shapes together, it seems like the `MouseListener` is pushed backwards and the `MouseListener` linked to `MainFrame` fires.

I have made a workaround the calls .GetCompontent() function  on the `JPanel`. But is must surely be possible to push forward a Components `MouseListener`?

Both the `JPanel` and the Components on it use the same `MouseListener`

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener,MouseInputListener {        

public MainFrame() {
    super("Tekenprogramma");
    //some other stuf
    drawPanel.addMouseListener(this);
    drawPanel.addMouseMotionListener(this);
}
```

and when shapes are created and added in the same class:

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource() == drawPanel) {
        Point pos = e.getPoint();
        switch(mode) {
//Some other cases...
        case RECTANGLE:
            shape = new Rectangle(pos);
            shape.addMouseListener(this);
            shape.addMouseMotionListener(this);
            storeAndExecute(new RectangleCommand(drawPanel,shape));
```

initially, the shapes do react to their own listener. But after I remove and read them (nested in a component without `MouseListener` (group)) They stop firing and the `drawPanel`'s `MouseListener` takes over.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java event propagation stopped](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605086/java-event-propagation-stopped)

Comment: It's a Swing design principle that only one component receives an event. What you have is a propagation precedence problem.