# Mouse events from JTextField do not get propagated

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, jtextfield

I am trying to listen to mouse events coming from both a JLabel and a JTextField. However, I am only able to listen to mouse events from JLabel, but not JTextField.

Consider this code:

```
class FieldPanel extends JPanel{
  JLabel label;
  JTextField text;

  public FieldPanel(){
    label = new JLabel("This is a test label");
    text = new JTextField("This is a test field");
    add(label);
    add(text);
  } 
}

class OuterPanel extends JPanel{
  FieldPanel fieldPanel;

  public OuterPanel(){
    fieldPanel = new FieldPanel();
    fieldPanel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Mouse pressed !!");
        }
    });
    add(fieldPanel);
  }
}

public class UITest{
    public static void main (String args[]){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        OuterPanel outerPanel = new OuterPanel();
        frame.getContentPane().add(outerPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The 'Mouse Pressed !!' message is displayed when I click on the JLabel. However, it does not get displayed when I click on the JTextField. Why is this the case?

Thanks!

Comment: Please add the mouse listener on the components on which you want to listen to events, in this case 'label' and 'text' and not the 'fieldPanel'

Comment: Hmmm but the problem is that I want the event to be propagated several layers above - from FieldPanel to OuterPanel to more outer panels. I added the mouse listener several layers above. The mouse events for JLabel get propagated properly, but not for JTextField.

Comment: checkout this post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605086/java-event-propagation-stopped, this has the same problem.

Comment: that's by design: mouseEvents are delivered to the first child (top of z-order) which is enabled (f.i. by registering a mouseListener) for them, they _do not_ bubble up the hierarchy. A JLabel isn't interested while a JTextField is: so the mouseEvent is delivered to the parent for the former and consumed by the latter. As of jdk7, you can decorate a container with a JLayer to see all events, for jdk6 it's predecessor is a project on java net http://jxlayer.java.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all the answers.

I found some sort of workaround. I am changing my code so that I listen directly to the `JTextField` component, as opposed to listening to the panel.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is an interesting question which kinda stomp on the finding accidentally. I will explain using the snippet code below.

```
class FieldPanel extends JPanel
{
    //JLabel label;
    JTextField text;

    public FieldPanel()
    {
        //label = new JLabel("This is a test label");
        text = new JTextField("This is a test field");
        //add(label);
        add(text);          
    }
}
```

when you run the code with the changes above, what we expect the output only the text field right? Then if you click on the area **near** to the textfield **outside** region, check in your console output, it actually print out *Mouse pressed !!*

So I went a little deeper to study into `JTextField`, it actually consist of the JTextField and JTextComponent. When you called the constructor `new JTextField("This is a test field");`, the text is actually set into the JTextComponent and not JTextField and I guess that is why when you click the **text**, it does not trigger the `mousePressed` event but it trigger only the `JTextField` only.

Below is my full code. If you want the text field to aware of the mouse pressed, consider implements `MouseAdapter()` in your `FieldPanel` class and add `addMouseListener(this)` for `text` and `label`.

```
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class MyMouseEvent extends JPanel
{

    public MyMouseEvent()
    {
        FieldPanel fieldPanel;
        fieldPanel = new FieldPanel();
        fieldPanel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
               @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event)
               {
                    System.out.println("Mouse pressed !!");
                }
        });
        add(fieldPanel);

    }

    class FieldPanel extends JPanel
    {
        //JLabel label;
        JTextField text;

        public FieldPanel()
        {
            //label = new JLabel("This is a test label");
            text = new JTextField("This is a test field");
            //add(label);
            add(text);          
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        MyMouseEvent evt = new MyMouseEvent();
        evt.setOpaque(true);
        frame.setContentPane(evt);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);     
    }

    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                createAndShowGUI();             
            }
        });

    }


}
```