# Should swing event handlers be queued after the event on the EDT?

Tags: java, swing, edt

Should swing event handling code be queued after the event on the EDT? If so, is it the responsibility of the event source to schedule the event handlers, or is it the responsibility of the event handler to schedule the actual handling code later?

Consider:

```
JButton b = new JButton();
b.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        /*
         * SNIP 1
         * do something that may affect other
         * components or generate new events...
         */

        // SNIP 2
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                /*
                 * do something that may affect other
                 * components or generate new events...
                 */
            }
        });
    }
});
```

`SNIP 1` runs handler code when the event is received. If the `JButton` takes responsibility for scheduling event by `EventQueue.invokeLater()`, then this is probably correct. `SNIP 2` receives the event, and takes responsibility of scheduling handler code after the event is received (and handled by all other listeners for this specific event type). Which is correct?

EDIT: Just for clarity, I want to schedule event handlers later on EDT because changing state in the first event handler may hide original state at the time of the event from other event handlers for the component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know its probably bad form to answer my own question, but I've come to the conclusion that one *should* queue event handlers *after* an event in Swing. The reason is this: each component can have more than one listener of a given type. You don't know what listeners are listening on any given component (swing itself may add listeners that you are unaware of), and you don't know what assumptions they make about the component tree, and the state of the tree when they handle an event.

Now, because each component can have multiple event handler for a certain event type, we don't know which event handler will be invoked first. If my event handler modifies the component tree, a subsequent event handler for the same event type will not see the component tree as it was at the time of the event. Instead, it will see the component tree as it was after my changes. The same problem exists for other application state which may be inspected and modified by two separate listeners of the same type on the same component. This is surely not right.

Secondly, there is a concept of events being dispatched by the EDT in a sequential order. ie. If event *x* happened before event *y* in real time, then the event handlers for *x* should run before the event handlers for *y*. Now, if my component, lets call it *c1*, has 2 event handlers for event `actionPerformed()` - *eh1* and *eh2*. When `actionPerformed()` is fired on *c1*, *eh1* is invoked to handle the event. It then modifies component *c2*, and causes a `itemStateChanged()` event to be fired on *c2*. Because this change queued after the first `actionPerformed()` event was complete (later on the EDT), and because *c2* does not queue the `itemStateChanged()` event to run later on the EDT, the `itemStateChanged()` event is handled by all its listeners. Only then does the second `actionPerformed()` listener (*eh2*) get to handle the original `actionPerformed()` event.

If *eh2* was also a listener to `itemStateChanged()` events on component *c2*, then it would appear to *eh2* that the `itemStateChanged()` event actually happened before the `actionPerformed()` event. This too is surely not right.

So that answers question 1. Yes, event handling code, which modifies application state or the component tree *should* be scheduled for execution *after* the event is processed. The event handlers should inspect whatever state they need to inspect at the time of the event, but react to the event (make changes) later on the EDT, by calling `EventQueue.invokeLater()`.

The second part of my question is about whose responsibility it is to ensure that handling of events happens after the event itself has taken place. In hindsight, this is a stupid question. The same problem exists if the event handlers are executed immediately when an event occurs, or if they are executed later by the component calling `EventQueue.invokeLater()`.

Incidentally, while I was researching this, I saw that not all Swing component do this uniformly. For example, `JCheckBox` fires the `itemStateChanged()` events immediately when the event occurs, while `JComponent` fires `componentResized()` (via is super class `java.awt.Component`) later on the EDT.

So it seems that the most robust way to handle events is to first inspect your state to make decisions about what actions you will take, then perform those actions later on the EDT. Any thoughts? I'd love to hear other people's insight into this.

Answer (score 1):

Please let me know though if I am misunderstanding your question, but all code in the Swing event Listeners is by run on the EDT, so there is no need to queue anything on to the EDT.  I have only rarely seen code such as in snip2 used in a Swing listener, and usually that's if the listener calls an anonymous inner Runnable in a background thread.

Comment: Yes, but the question is about WHERE on the EDT. Components can have multiple listeners for each event type. The first event handler may change some state in the gui component or elsewhere before subsequent handlers have the opportunity to check the state at the time of the event being fired.

Comment: I recollect reading that there is no way to predict which listener will fire first, and that code should be written with this in mind.

Answer (score 1):

As @HFOE notes, elements in the [`EventQueue`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html) are *sequential* and *ordered*; `SNIP 2` shouldn't be required. If I understand your requirement, one approach might be to *forward* the event to any other interested listener(s), as suggested in this [question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159803/eventlistenerlist-firing-order).

Comment: The more I think about this, the more I'm convinced that `SNIP 2` is indeed required. Especially considering the whole idea of event handlers getting an _ordered_ sequence of events. Without queuing changes to the swing components on the EDT, you risk causing calls to other event handlers while handling your first event. That is, of course, if the modified swing components do not schedule the new events for later execution, which is really what the question is about. I'll actually post a complete answer to my own question after I've thoroughly researched this.

Comment: `SNIP 2` would be required only if `actionPerformed()` were to be executed from from a thread other than the EDT. I look forward to your analysis.