# How to avoid coupling the View and the Controller in Swing

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, actionlistener, propertychangelistener

I have recently come across a problem trying to implement Model-View-Controller in **Swing**.

I have a GUI class which consists of sub-panels, and those sub-panels consist of other sub-panels. Now in one of these sub-sub panels there is a `JButton`. In the `ActionListener` for this `JButton` I want to call a method in the controller. In order to do this I would need to pass the controller deep into the bowels of the GUI to the sub-sub panel where the `JButton` resides. Then in this sub-sub panel I would need to attach an `ActionListener` to the `JButton` and fill out the `actionPerformed()` by calling the method that I wanted to call in the controller.

I'm sure you all see the problem. Is there any good way of avoiding passing the controller deep into the bowels of the GUI.

My only thought was to make the controller a Singleton to decouple it from the view, but I have heard that Singleton's are usually evil.

Any advice on this matter would be most appreciated.

Comment: ِAlso https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10285582/ would help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of passing in a reference to the controller, let the controller *listen* to the view, as suggested by the *indirect association* pictured [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller). Adding a `PropertyChangeListener`, illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9346946/230513), is ideal for this. When the view needs to call upon the controller, it simply invokes `firePropertyChange()`.

A more expedient approach is to give the controller a separate view for certain operations such as the `reset()` method shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3072979/230513).