# How to wire one pane to another

Tags: java, swing, oop, user-interface, netbeans

How do I wire output to `paneWithList`?

`PaneWithList` has a listener on its `JList` so that the selected row is output to the console.  How can I direct that output to the `JTextPane` on output?

Could `PaneWithList` fire an event which `Main` picks up?  Would [PropertyChangeSupport](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeSupport.html) suffice?

Main.java:

```
package dur.bounceme.net;

import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;

public class Main {

    private static JTabbedPane tabs;
    private static PaneWithList paneWithList;
    private static PaneWithTable paneWithTable;
    private static Output output;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        tabs = new javax.swing.JTabbedPane();
        paneWithList = new PaneWithList();
        paneWithTable = new PaneWithTable();
        tabs.addTab("list", paneWithList);
        tabs.addTab("table", paneWithTable);
        tabs.addTab("output", output);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just have the `JTextPane` register itself as a listener to the same `JList`.

Comment: addListener(this)?  can you expand that a bit?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's an example using the [*observer pattern*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern), also seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3072979/230513), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9346946/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11832979/230513). Note that it would also be possible to listen to the combo's model.

[image]

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import javax.swing.*;

/**
* @see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern
* @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/10523401/230513
*/
public class PropertyChangeDemo {

    public PropertyChangeDemo() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setResizable(false);
        f.add(new ObserverPanel());
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                PropertyChangeDemo example = new PropertyChangeDemo();
            }
        });
    }
}

class ObserverPanel extends JPanel {

    private JLabel title = new JLabel("Value received: ");
    private JLabel label = new JLabel("null", JLabel.CENTER);

    public ObserverPanel() {
        this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("ObserverPanel"));
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        panel.add(title);
        panel.add(label);
        this.add(panel);
        ObservedPanel observed = new ObservedPanel();
        observed.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e) {
                if (e.getPropertyName().equals(ObservedPanel.PHYSICIST)) {
                    String value = e.getNewValue().toString();
                    label.setText(value);
                }
            }
        });
        this.add(observed);
    }
}

class ObservedPanel extends JPanel {

    public static final String PHYSICIST = "Physicist";
    private static final String[] items = new String[]{
        "Alpher", "Bethe", "Gamow", "Dirac", "Einstein"
    };
    private JComboBox combo = new JComboBox(items);
    private String oldValue;

    public ObservedPanel() {
        this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("ObservedPanel"));
        combo.addActionListener(new ComboBoxListener());
        this.add(combo);
    }

    private class ComboBoxListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            String newValue = (String) combo.getSelectedItem();
            firePropertyChange(PHYSICIST, oldValue, newValue);
            oldValue = newValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I better understand how firePropertyChange propogates, thank you.  Not quite sure how you passed actual values around, need to read again, but this was the missing piece for me.

Comment: Here's a related [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11832979/230513) that uses a modeless dialog.

Comment: wow! magnificent! I wonder if Observer Pattern demands to create an instance of _Observed Panel_ into the _Observer Panel_

Comment: @JG.: I would say no; `PropertyChangeEvent` is only one way to effect the [_observer pattern_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) in Swing; more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3072979/230513).

Answer (score 3):

I'd be use [JMenu with JMenuItems](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html) with contents layed by using [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) rather than very complicated [JTabbedPane(s)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html)

Comment: +1 good alternative, often wired using [`Action`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html).

Comment: Action doesn't seem to work across all Swing controls however..?

Answer (score 1):

For my own reference, and for anyone using the Netbeans GUI builder, this works so far as it goes:

The PanelWithList class:

```
package dur.bounceme.net;

public class PanelWithList extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    public PanelWithList() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jList1 = new javax.swing.JList();
        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();

        jList1.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel() {
            String[] strings = { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5" };
            public int getSize() { return strings.length; }
            public Object getElementAt(int i) { return strings[i]; }
        });
        jList1.setSelectionMode(javax.swing.ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        jList1.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                jList1MouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });
        jList1.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                jList1KeyReleased(evt);
            }
        });
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jList1);

        jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
        jTextArea1.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jTextArea1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(54, 54, 54)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 247, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 308, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(167, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(35, 35, 35)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane2)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1))
                .addContainerGap(166, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jList1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                    
        row();
    }                                   

    private void jList1KeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                   
        row();
    }                                  
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JList jList1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
    // End of variables declaration                   

    private void row() {
        Object o = jList1.getSelectedValue();
        String s = (String)o;
        jTextArea1.setText(s);
        this.firePropertyChange("list", -1, 1);
    }
}
```

and Frame.java as a driver:

```
package dur.bounceme.net;

public class Frame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public Frame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        jTabbedPane1 = new javax.swing.JTabbedPane();
        panelWithList1 = new dur.bounceme.net.PanelWithList();
        panelWithTable1 = new dur.bounceme.net.PanelWithTable();
        newJPanel1 = new dur.bounceme.net.PanelWithCombo();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        panelWithList1.addPropertyChangeListener(new java.beans.PropertyChangeListener() {
            public void propertyChange(java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                panelWithList1PropertyChange(evt);
            }
        });
        jTabbedPane1.addTab("tab1", panelWithList1);
        jTabbedPane1.addTab("tab2", panelWithTable1);
        jTabbedPane1.addTab("tab3", newJPanel1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 937, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(jTabbedPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 913, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addContainerGap()))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 555, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(jTabbedPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 521, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addContainerGap(22, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    private void panelWithList1PropertyChange(java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        System.out.println("panelWithList1PropertyChange ");

    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /*
         * Set the Nimbus look and feel
         */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /*
         * If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the
         * default look and feel. For details see
         * http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Frame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Frame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Frame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Frame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /*
         * Create and display the form
         */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new Frame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JTabbedPane jTabbedPane1;
    private dur.bounceme.net.PanelWithCombo newJPanel1;
    private dur.bounceme.net.PanelWithList panelWithList1;
    private dur.bounceme.net.PanelWithTable panelWithTable1;
    // End of variables declaration
}
```

The key being that `panelWithList1PropertyChange` is the listener on 'panelWithList' itself.

Because `PanelWithList.firePropertyChange("list", -1, 1);` cannot send Object nor String that I see, I'm not exactly sure how to get the **value** selected all the way from the JList up to the JFrame.

Hmm, well the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#firePropertyChange%28java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20boolean%29) says yes it can send Objects.  Have to check that out.

I think it's necessary to get some info about the model which the JList is using up to the JFrame.  However, doesn't that break MVC?  Or maybe that's the wrong approach.

Comment: For reference, [tag:jcalendar] is a fairly accessible example of a `JComponent` that implements `PropertyChangeListener`. See also [*A Swing Architecture Overview*](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/architecture/).