# general way to listen to all change events on swing objects

Tags: java, swing, events

Is there a library or technique to listen to all changeable events on swing ui objects? Specifically the data.

For instance, I have a JPanel with a JTextArea, JCheckBox, JComboBox, etc. Is there a common way to say "If the data in this changes, notify me"? I don't care about borders changing, and other UI event stuff, just user data changing.

I've tried propertychangelister, but I can't seem to find a common property, or a common class that will do this.

Answer (score 3):

No, nothing common. You can listen directly to the model for those components that have a [*separable model*](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/architecture/). You can wrap the change in a `PropertyChangeListener`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10523401/230513), in order to customize the message. The [*observer pattern*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3072979/230513).