# How to set ActionListener to listen to another ActionListener to fire an event in a different class?

Tags: java, swing, spring-mvc, jframe, jpanel

I'm trying to figure out how I can have a class listen to another. So this is the idea.

I have a `MainFrame` class, which is simply a container class, JFrame container, that takes an argument of type JPanel. Basically I want this container class to be able to switch between frames depending on what my other class, `FrameSwitcher`, will tell it to do.

The other classes are: `FrameSwitcher, MainMenu and ScoreBoards`.

The idea is that, let's say `MainMenu`, will contain 4 buttons, each one will listen, BUT will NOT change the frames. Rather it will somehow - and this is the part I need help with - send to the `FrameSwitcher` what button was clicked, and this information will then be sent to `MainFrame` to switch to the appropriate frames.

Answer (score 3):

You may be looking for the [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern), discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3072979/230513). In particular, a [`PropertyChangeListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeListener.html), illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10523401/230513), may be a useful approach to loose coupling.

Also consider letting each view export an `Action` that selects itself from a `CardLayout`, as suggested in [*How to Use Actions*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) and [*How to Use CardLayout*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).

Answer (score 2):

`FrameSwitcher` should keep `ActionListeners` added to the menu. On click it changes it's state and call MainFrame's method `switchTo(argumentWhereToSwitch);`

Comment: I understand the concept, but how does `FrameSwitcher` keep `ActionListeners` added the menu?

Comment: There is a `protected` instance of [`EventListenerList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/EventListenerList.html) which is declared in `JComponent`, you can use it to maintain a list of registered `ActionListener`s.  It has methods for getting all the `ActionListener`s registered as an array.  You would simply then need to iterate this list and call `actionPerformed` on each

Comment: So I'm going to add the JButtons in MainMenu to the `EvenListenerList` and pass access it from `FrameSwitcher`? Then change the panels?