# Add item to GUI jCombo box

Tags: java, swing, observer-pattern, propertychangelistener

I have a Java program with a model and a GUI. On my Frame (that `implements Observer`) I have put a jcombobox with a list of registration from my model (that `extends Observable`).

When I click on a button add registration the list in my model changed. And than I do

```
setChanged(); 
notifyObservers();
```

In my update method I want to make change the values of the jcombobox. I tried with a `repaint()` or something like that, but my combobox doesn't change. I am sure I go to my update method, but I don't know how I have to change the jcombobox.

Can someone help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `update()` implementation should obtain a reference to the combo's model and either set the selected item or add a new item, as warranted. A `PropertyChangeEvent`, illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10523401/230513), may be an alternative, as it can include both old and new values.

Comment: Ok thanks that works. I took my comboBox model and used the insertItemAt(args,index) method.