# set gui contents from another class

Tags: java, swing

I want to be able to change the content of a some `JLabel` objects from another class. I have a `GUI` class containing all GUI objects (`JFrame`, `JPanel`, etc.). Let's say I have only one `JLabel`:

```
public class GUI {
    private JLabel label;

    public GUI() {
        initialize();//initializes all objects
    }

    public void update(String s) {
        this.label.setText(s);
    }
}
```

`GUI` has a public function `update(String)` that I hope to call from another class.

My main class is called `App`:

```
public class App {
    private static GUI window;

    public static void main( String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    window = new GUI();
                    App.updateTxt("some string");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
         });
    }

    public  static void updateTxt(String s) {
        window.update(s);
    }
}
```

This solution does not work, however, `GUI.update(String)` is working perfectly when called inside the `GUI` class.
I checked the solution proposed by Paul in:
[Access GUI components from another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22833328/access-gui-components-from-another-class) but I did not understand it.
So how can I invoke a method on `GUI` from another class to change the UI?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so we can easier understand your problem. The code posted here give us neither the information about how you GUI is built, nor how you call the method `updateTxt`.

Comment: thank you for your reply Janus, the idea is to call App.updateTxt() from any class since App is where window (the instance of GUI) is saved. Let's say we call App.updateTxt("some string") just after the Instantiation  of GUI => result: Unfortunately nothing changed in window

Comment: Swing components have a repaint(), revalidate(), and doLayout() method. One of those should probably be able to redraw whichever pieces you want. However, doLayout is not something that you should be taking responsibility for, that's the layout engines responsibility.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the code posted, `GUI.update(String)` is never invoked as it is called from within `App.updateText(String)` which you never invoke as part of `App.main(String[])`.

Try the following changes to `App`:

```
public class App {
    private static GUI window;

    public static void main( String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        window = new GUI();
        Thread.sleep(1000); // Pause for 1 second.       
        updateText("Hello, world!"); // Update the label with new text.
    }

    public  static void updateTxt(String s) {
        window.update(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks Janus, I tried this, Unfortunately still no changes on the window.
In fact,GUI.update() is called and executed indeed, but the changes on the GUI aren't displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You should take care of threading, see: [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

That said, try something like this:

```
public void update(final String s) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            this.label.setText(s);
        }
    });
}
```