# Update label of a JPanel when change the value of one variable from another JPanel

Tags: java, swing, events, jpanel, jlabel

I am new on Java.

I have developed an application with some different `JPanels` (using a `BorderLayout`, 3 panels in this case).

In panel 1, I have a JLabel and a variable (a class) that is related with its value (method get);
in panel 2, I updated the value of the variable (method set) because it is done when an action is performed in this second panel.

How Could I get the value of the JLabel in panel 1 updated?

I don't know how to trigger an event or something similar after updating the value from panel 2 and how to make panel 1 to listen to this change.

Let me explain a bit more. I have a JFrame with two JPanels and I update the model from one panel. Once the model is updated, the JLabel from the other JPanel should be updated:
Main: JFrame

```
public class MainClass extends JFrame
{
    public MainClass()
    {
        // JPanel 1
        ....        
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(400,300);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setTitle("Test");
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);
        // JPanel 1
        this.add(west, BorderLayout.WEST);
        // JPanel 2
        this.add(board, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // put your code here
        new MainClass ();
    }
}
```

JPanel 1

```
public class West extends JPanel
{
    contFase = new Contador(titulo, valor);
    JLabel lblTitulo;
    ...
    lblTitulo.setText = contFase.getText();
    this.add(lblTitulo);
    ...
}
```

JPanel 2

```
public class Board extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
    ....
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        ...
        //Here Label of panel 1 should be updated with the model
        contFase.setValor(contFase.getValor() + pacman.comerElemento(fase.getPacdots(), fase.getPowerPellets()));
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Save all the GUI fields in a GUI model class that all of the JPanels access.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to wire one JPane to another JPane](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523343/how-to-wire-one-jpane-to-another-jpane)

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Could you post a brief example please?

Comment: @JG: Sure.  Here's an article I wrote that has model classes and GUI classes - [Qlocktwo with Java Swing](http://java-articles.info/articles/?p=555)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have little idea how your code looks like because you didn't show any, but here is an example of how to edit a `JLabel` when an action is taken (in this case - pressing a button). The layout of the components on panels does not matter, but I put 2 panels like you wanted.

```
public class ValueUpdate extends JFrame {

    int x = 0;
    final JLabel label = new JLabel(String.valueOf(x));

    ValueUpdate() {

        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();

        panel1.add(label);

        JButton btn = new JButton("Increment");
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                x++;
                label.setText(String.valueOf(x));
            }
        });

        panel2.add(btn);

        getContentPane().add(panel1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        getContentPane().add(panel2, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new ValueUpdate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe simply make JPanel1 managed from JFrame and make an update from JPanel2 to the JFrame? (to update JPanel1)

Comment: @AgusP. I don't understand what you mean by making a component manage another component. Right now a button in `panel2` changes a label in`panel1`. They are both inside the `JFrame` which holds the value one is changing and the other is displaying.

Comment: Ok, let me explain. I have not a "Component" that raise one ActionPerformed. Really, this is a "game" and in JPanel2 I have a Timer. so, there is a case in which the main character do something (in panel 2) and then the label in JPanel1 the label should be updated. I think that it should be similar to your logic but maybe is more that in my architecture something is wrong and every change should be done from "MainClass". Any suggest?

Comment: @AgusP. `actionPerformed` **must** be called by a component because you must register the `ActionListener` to a component. It does not matter in which panels your components are. Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) because your code shows us nothing to go with.

Comment: Thanks, really, answering to my question, it is.