# Pass parameter to another panel swing java

Tags: java, swing, oop, jpanel

I have a problem.
For example: We have MainFrame, on this form we have mainPanel. Next, creates new classes with names FirstPanel and SecondPanel wich extends JPanel. Now in MainFrame writes:

```
public MainFrame() {
        initComponents();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        Main main = new Main();
        main.setMainPanel(mainPanel);
        mainPanel.setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
        mainPanel.add( PANELS_LIST.get(0) );
        mainPanel.validate();
}
```

PANELS_LIST - arrayList with all panels. PANELS_LIST.get(0) - jpanel with name FirstPanel .
After this we will see FirstPanel. On the FirstPanel we have button. So, on this button click I want to change mainPanel state (need SecondPanel overwrites FirstPanel). How can i do this? Tried to send mainPanel like a param with creating setter or getter but doesn't work..
At all I need mainPanel to be accesable from any panel in any class

PS: ofcourse I can set mainPanel like a public and static, but.. I think this is bad solution

Comment: Some approaches are examined int his possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10523343/230513).

Comment: *"FirstPanel and SecondPanel wich extends JPanel"*  It is likely neither of those should extend `JPanel`.  Instead they should just be instances of panel.  Making them a separate class has caused this difficulty, and though it is possible to correct it while they are still extending panel, it makes little sense to do so.

Comment: Why just an instance? There will be a lot of other functions.

Comment: Your question is very unclear; @AndrewThompson's point is that panels typically enclose view components; use `CardLayout` to change views; use property changes to communicate changes.

Comment: create a static field in your MainFrame e.g. main and in the constructor of MainFrame class assign 'this' to main e.g. main = this; now you can access the main class anywhere by just using the MainFrame.main

Comment: Tip: Add @trashgod (or whoever, the `@` is important) to notify the person of a new comment.  *"There will be a lot of other functions."*  So?  What methods of the extended panels are overridden?  That is the ***only*** situation I can think of where it actually makes sense to override.  Otherwise, these panels come into being mainly because of GUI editors.  Are you using a GUI editor, or laying out the panels yourself?

Comment: @Muhammad *"create a static field.."*  ..and create more problems than you solve.

Comment: Agree with @ Andrew, that @Muhammad's advice is not good advice since you'd be throwing out the baby with the bathwater. Making it static makes it hard to do unit testing, hard to enhance and upgrade.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson
I'm using netbeans like a gui editor. And I will not use cardlayout because it isn't the thing i need

Comment: `"So, on this button click I want to change mainPanel state (need SecondPanel overwrites FirstPanel)."` -- this sure sounds like a perfect use-case for CardLayout use, and using the NetBeans GUI editor does not prevent one from using a CardLayout where needed.