# Adding values in a dataset only if a checkbox is checked

Tags: java, actionlistener, jcombobox

I have a loop who adds values in a dataset in 3 series:

```
for (int j = 0; j < gcArrayList.size(); j++) {
    if (j % 3 == 0) {
        datasetBar.addValue(Float.parseFloat((String) gcArrayList.get(j)),series1, gcDateList.get(j / 3));
    } else if (j % 3 == 1) {
        datasetBar.addValue(Float.parseFloat((String) gcArrayList.get(j)),series2, gcDateList.get(j / 3));
    } else {
        datasetBar.addValue(Float.parseFloat((String) gcArrayList.get(j)),series3, gcDateList.get(j / 3));
    }       
}
```

Then I want those dataset to add values in each series **only if** their checkbox is checked( I have 3 checkboxes for `"First array"`, `"Second array"` , `"Third array"`).

```
    array1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JCheckBox ch = (JCheckBox) e.getSource();

            if(ch.isSelected()) {

            } else {

            }
        }
    });
```

Also the checkboxes are in a different class than the method who adds values in datasets.

I don't know how to make the connection between the `ActionListener` of the checkbox and the `datasetBar.addValue()`.

I tried something like:

```
if(j % 3 ==0 && array1.isSelected()) ...
```

I knew it won't work but I think the solution is somewhere in that area...
Can anybody help me?

Thanks.

Comment: One approach is shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13919878/230513).

Comment: Thanks. I was looking at that approach but didn't found out how to apply it to my problem. Can you explain me, please, how that can help me? I don't know how to make the 'addValue' function listen to the checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know how to make the `addValue()` function listen to the check box.

This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13919878/230513) stores the state of each check box the `TableModel` associated with a `JTable`. Alternatively, use a `List<Boolean>` as your model. Each check box should have an instance of an `ActionListener` that updates the corresponding list element. Use the check box's `putClientProperty()` method to keep track of the list index for each check box. As shown in this [`PropertyChangeDemo`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10523401/230513), you can add a [`PropertyChangeListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/propertychangelistener.html) to the enclosing `Container` of the components you want to observe and fire an appropriate `PropertyChangeEvent` in a check box's `ActionListener`.

Rather than adding values to each series, this related [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11895709/230513) extends `AbstractAction` to allow a `JCheckBox` to toggle the *visibility* of individual series.

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    renderer.setSeriesVisible(i, !renderer.getSeriesVisible(i));
}
```

[image]