# Passing value from JFrame to internal Frame

Tags: java, swing

I have `jFrame1` that contains a `jtextfield1` and a `button1`.
I also have `jFrame2` that holds a `desktopPane1` and that `desktopPane1` holds `internalFrame1` which contains `jtextfield2`.
What i want to do is, the text from `jtextfield1` should be passed to `jtextfield2` when i click the `button1`.
i tried the

`internalFrame1 access=new internalFrame1();
access.jtextfield2.setText(jtextfield1.getText());`

of course I put that code inside may `button1`.
i didn't get any error, but i didn't get any result as well. How to do it? Help me pleeease.

Comment: model-view-controller

Comment: is that a hint? i dont get it..
could you please give me,at least, an example?
please.. please..

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10523401/230513).

Comment: You also should avoid any excessive use of multiple JFrames, since it can be very confusing for the user. There are several better alternatives, see here for examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-or-bad-practice

Comment: @hamena314 i only have 2 jframes.. 1 is for log in window.. and the other one is my main window.