# How to change the JLabel value from another class?

Tags: java, swing, scope, jlabel

I have two classes, in the first file there are `JLabel` components and in the other class, there is an input dialog from which I wanted the user-submitted number to be displayed in the first class but can't get it to work.

In the first file, labels are created with Netbeans Swing and are public.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    Object[] values = { "Twenty", "Ten", "Five" };
    int pickedValues = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Choose which label do you want to edit", "Choice", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, values, values[0]);
    
    if(pickedValues == 2){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);            
        String inputValue = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Write the value");
        inputValue = sc.nextLine();
        int valueInt = Integer.parseInt(inputValue);
        labelFive.setText(String.valueOf(valueInt));
    }
}
```

labelFive is the name of the jLabel in the first file, I have no idea what to try here.

Comment: Add a method in the other class to set the text. And create a reference to it in your first class.

Comment: Don't let the GUI editor dictate your program's design; here's one [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10523401/230513); please [edit] your question to include a [mre] that shows your revised approach.

Comment: Besides the good advice from @trashgod & JaJP, don't mix console (`System.in`) and GUI operations. The `inputValue` should have a value by the moment the input pane has closed (unless the user cancels it).