# How to fire JSlider change listener?

Tags: java, swing, listener, jslider, changelistener

How can I programmatically fire the change listener of a `JSlider`?

Comment: refer this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/changelistener.html

Comment: I second @kleopatra 's question. Sounds like you are trying to do something the wrong way.

Comment: @kleopatra @ Guillaume Polet I found I needed it for the workaround for a "bug" reported here: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-5070992 Maybe that's what OP also was working on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you want to notify listeners of the slider, you would use this:

```
    ChangeEvent ce = new ChangeEvent(slider);
    for(ChangeListener cl : slider.getChangeListeners()){
        cl.stateChanged(ce);
    }
```

You shouldn't need to fire the change event directly unless you're extending the class and adding some new funky functionality.  In that case, the `fireStateChanged()` method is protected, so you should have access.

Comment: while technically correct, I'm really reluctant to upvote: if firing the change manually seems to be needed, most probably something is really, really wrong somewhere else.

Comment: @kleopatra: This [scenario](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2159803/230513) might be a reasonable use-case.

Comment: @trashgod might be - hard to tell without context and a tad improbable :-)

Comment: @kleopatra: On reflection, this approach (implicitly) short-circuits the loose coupling afforded by `ChangeEvent`. I'd say it's a trade-off for closely related listeners.

Answer (score 0):

`slider.setValue(value)` will fire a state changed event.

Answer (score -1):

have look at ChangeListener, examples [here](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/GUI/components/70sliders/20changelistener.html) and [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/TrackingchangestoaJSliderwithaChangeListener.htm)