# Java - TableModelListeners and DataModelEvents

Tags: java, swing, tablemodel, abstracttablemodel, defaulttablemodel

When should I create my own TableModelListeners and DataModelEvents?

I know the difference and use of a `DefaultTableModel`,  `AbstractTableModel` and `TableModel`.

I have seen in many online Java examples where TableModelListeners and DataModelEvents are explicitly created while creating a class (custom model) that extends either the DefaultTableModel  and the AbstractTableModel class.

This is my understanding:

1. If I am extending a `DefaultTableModel` then this model already knows how to create DataModelEvents and the TableModelListeners (so that I do not have to add them) listening/observing to these events and also knows to notify the TableModelListeners.
2. If I am extending an AbstractTableModel then this model already knows how to create DataModelEvents and the TableModelListeners (so that I do not have to add them)  listening/observing to these events. But I have to explicitly invoke the firetablechanged() or similar methods to notify the TableModelListeners about the event.
3. If I am implementing a TableModel then this model already knows how to create DataModelEvents but **does not** have any TableModelListeners (so that I have to add them) listening/observing to these events. And also I have to explicitly invoke the firetablechanged() or similar methods to notify the TableModelListeners about the event.

Comment: not clear and nice described question, maybe reason for down_voter,

Comment: may be the person who down voted my question did not read the title.

Comment: You should rarely need to implement `TableModelListener`.  I would tend use them if I was performing additional calculations off the table model (such as summing columns or rows) and wanted to know when the data in the table changed.  I can't think a reason to ever have to create a `TableModelEvent`, unless you've opted to implement directly from the `TableModel` interface, but, quite frankly, I think you'd have to be mad when `AbstractTableModel` provides all the event notification mechanisms for you.  You third point is invalid.  `TableModel` has no capacity to create anything...

Comment: @MadProgrammer...thanks for clarifying my question. Why is my third point invalid. I did say that it does not have any listeners and I have to add them. I believe you are saying that it does not even have the firetablechanged() or similar methods to notify and I have to create them as well.

Comment: @user547453 TableModel is an interface, it has no capacity to create anything, nor does it define any functionality for firing events. It has methods adding/removing listeners, but how that is achieved is up to the implementations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I defer to @mKorbel on `DefaultTableModel`, which is well suited to cases that can rely on its straightforward mutators. It is limited by the internal use of `Vector`, a supported but obsolescent `Collection` that carries (possibly) needless synchronization overhead.

`AbstractTableModel` offers much more [flexibility](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data) in exposing your application's data model to a `JTable` view. It should be used in cases for which `DefaultTableModel` is unsuitable.

Focusing on your question, `JTable` implements `TableModelListener`, and it listens to its own `TableModel`. An arbitrary number of *other* views can also listens to the same model; [`DisplayPanel`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13919878/230513) is an example that listens to an `AbstractTableModel` named `CheckModel`. Your `TableModel` should fire a suitable `TableModelEvent` if it contains the data needed by your view(s) to update themselves. If not, you can define your own event *types* using the same `EventListenerList` mechanism used by `JTable`, described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/EventListenerList.html), and mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2159803/230513).

Comment: Thanks @trashgod....This is what I was missing. I also did not realize the JTable is the one that implements the TableModelListener.

Comment: Exactly; _all_ class instances listening to a given `TableModel`, including the `JTable` itself, receive the fired event.

Answer (score 3):

1. `DefaultTableModel` (`extends AbstractTableModel`), by default all notifiers (`DataModelEvents`) are implemented and correctly, by default to have to override only editable (for `TableCellEditor` and if needed) and `Column Class` (not required in most cases)
2. `AbstractTableModel`, have to override all `required methods`, otherwise they don't work in compare with `DefaultTableModel`, and work only how these methods are implemented, by default all notifiers (`DataModelEvents`) is required to override too, otherwise `JTables view` doesn't shows proper or expected value
3. `DefaultTableModel` is based on premature `Arrays` (even I saw `HashMap` in `DefaultTableModel`, no issue), `AbstractTableModel` allows to implements various `arrays types` without any restrictions (implemented in concrete arrays API)
4. by using `DefaultTableModel` is everything allowed, everything is accessible (methods implemented in API), in compare with `AbstractTableModel`,
5. `AbstractTableModel` is about restictions, modifying, add or override methods,
6. for `JTable` without any definitions for `XxxTableModel` is used  `DefaultTableModel`

Comment: @mKorbel....your response does not answer my question. My question is in the title itself.

Comment: @user547453: Please edit your question to recapitulate the title, which may be easily overlooked.