# Is it possible to find event fire chain in java?

Tags: java, events

I wanted to know do events have a priority in being fired or they are fired in the order they were registered?
For example I have a table and has two events on it,SelectionChanged and MouseClick,which one fires first if I click on a row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the class `EventQueue`. This class has all what you need, including the origin event (mouse or key event) for your selection event.

Answer (score 0):

if the order of firing the events is important for You, just set up a chain of listeners, ie Listener one will notify listener two etc, so you could handle the order.

Also check this for more information:

[Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159803/eventlistenerlist-firing-order)

Answer (score 0):

personally, I think Observer pattern is usefully for your,it's deserved.