# How to make multiple jtables share a single event handler method

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am new to Java so please be gentle lol. My question is this... I am used to C#, where making multiple items and having all their..say...mouse clicked events, go to one method that would sort out what control fired it etc. The thing is, I cant figure out how to do this in Java. I have several JTables and needs ONE method to handle the tablemodellistener events.

```
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

public class SimpleTableDemo ... implements TableModelListener {
    ...
    public SimpleTableDemo() {
        ...
        table.getModel().addTableModelListener(this);
        ...
    }

    public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
        int row = e.getFirstRow();
        int column = e.getColumn();
        TableModel model = (TableModel)e.getSource();
        String columnName = model.getColumnName(column);
        Object data = model.getValueAt(row, column);

        ...// Do something with the data...
    }
    ...
}
```

so I tried changing "table.getModel().addTableModelListener(this);"

to:

table.getModel().addTableModelListener([MyMethod of type TableModelListener]);

but it will not compile. Please provide a complete example or really good hint. Thanks!

EDIT:

I got the code from here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#modelchange

Answer (score 1):

Java event handling (unfortunately) doesn't work like C# event handling does.

So

> table.getModel().addTableModelListener([MyMethod of type
>   TableModelListener]);

Will not work.

---

### UPDATE for Java 8 and above

With Java 8 and lambda expressions the above statement is no longer true. If you have a method in your class with a signature matching `tableChanged(TableModelEvent)` of `TableModelListener` you can write

```
private void tableChangedEventHandler(TableModelEvent evt) {
    //do stuff
}

table.getModel().addTableModelListener(this::tableChangedEventHandler);
```

Note that you don't need to implement the interface and the method name should not match the name of the method in the interface.

---

Now to your question, you need to implement `TableModelListener` at some other class that its sole purpose is to handle the events, let's call it `MyTableModelListener`. After that, you either instantiate it wherever you need it

```
table.getModel().addTableModelListener(new MyTableModelListener());
```

or you make it singleton if you **really** need one method to handle the event as you said

```
table.getModel().addTableModelListener(MyTableModelListener.getInstance());
```

Comment: so, "MyTableModelListener" would be a class of type "MyTableModelListener" with what method(s)?

Comment: `MyTableModelListener` will implement `TableModelListener`, an interface. So it will have to contain all methods that the interface contains, namely tableChanged(TableModelEvent e). For details see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/TableModelListener.html

Answer (score 1):

In this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13919878/230513), a single `TableModel` has several listeners, including the `JTable` itself and an adjacent `JList`. Each `JComponent` contains an `EventListenerList`, examined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3072979/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2159803/230513), which contains an arbitrary number of event listeners for that model.