# What is the order of fired events in a combobox ItemListener

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, itemlistener

I'm adding an ItemListener to a combobox and I want to know if the event ItemEvent.DESELECTED is always triggered BEFORE the event ItemEvent.SELECTED, or if the order is unspecified.

On a simple example, it seems that DESELECTED is fired before, but can I trust this example?

```
    combo = new JComboBox<String>(new String[}{"A","B","C"});
    combo.addItemListener(new ItemListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(final ItemEvent e)
        {
            if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
            {
                logger.debug("{} selected", e.getItem());
                // Load the file selected in the JTextArea using JTextArea.setDocument()
            }
            else if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED)
            {
                logger.debug("{} deselected", e.getItem());
                // If doc in the textarea has been modified, save it now
            }
        }
    });
```

To add context to the question, I use the combo to select a file to load in a JTextArea. The user can edit the file via the textarea. If she selects another file in the combo, I want to inform her that the previous file has been edited and ask her confirmation to save the edits. Can I implement this safely in the ItemListener of the combo? By safely, I mean can I be sure that if I call textArea.getText() at this point in time (item DESELECTED), am I sure that the textarea is not already filled up with the content of the new file to load?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [general](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2159803/230513), the order is *not* specified. In particular, the combo selection and text display is irrelevant to the underlying `Document` state. If the user elects to continue editing, simply restore the modified `Document` to the text area.