# How to return values from Slider to control in swing Java

Tags: java, swing, color-picker

First I have implemented this class  ColorValueSliderControl as described in this link [ColorValueSliderControl](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/UseSlidertocontrolthecolorRGBvalue.htm)

Now I have would like to return the values of this method  of the Class TColor to another separated independant  class

```
public class ColorValueSliderControl extends JFrame {
  public ColorValueSliderControl() {
    getContentPane().add(new TColor());
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(500, 500);
    setVisible(true);
  }
/*  Not needed 
   public static void main(String arg[]) {
    new ColorValueSliderControl();
  }*/
}
class TColor extends JPanel {
  ......
 //I want to return the result of this method to another class
  public Color  setBackgroundColor() {
   float [] colors = new float[3];
   color = new Color(redValue, greenValue, blueValue, alphaValue);
   return(color); 
    ......


  }
```

Thank you

Comment: instantiate `TColor` in the class where you want the result of function, then call the function using that instance.

Comment: but I was wondering if it's a good thing to do

Comment: In which class you are going to use that function?

Comment: Also consider the approach examined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2159803/230513).

Comment: @jackjay in a third random class completely not connected to the Color chooser

Comment: Use some kind of observer pattern which allows other objects to monitor changes the occur in TColor. You could also use a JDialog instead of JFrame, which allow you to display a modal dialog, allow the user to value and when closed you could use a getter to get the actual value

Comment: I will see what suits the best UI , thank you all for your advice

Comment: 1) `ColorValueSliderControl` See also [`JColorChooser`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JColorChooser.html) 2) Generally it's better to simply use instances of frames and panels, than to extend them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did solve my own problem , what I did is simply implement the color panel into my existing J Frame and it was much easier go get result of the chosen color by using getter and setter , and to update the color all I needed is use the existing Listener  that exist in TColor class